# Read PDF in Python and convert to text in PDF

Tags: python, pdftotext

I have used this code to convert pdf to text.

```
input1 = '//Home//Sai Krishna Dubagunta.pdf'
output = '//Home//Me.txt'
os.system(("pdftotext %s %s") %( input1, output))
```

I have created the Home directory and pasted the source file in it.

The  output I get is

```
1
```

And no file with .txt was created. Where is the Problem?

Comment: check error code 1 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your expression

```
("pdftotext %s %s") %( input1, output)
```

will translate to

```
pdftotext //Home//Sai Krishna Dubagunta.pdf //Home//Me.txt
```

which means that the first parameter passed to `pdftotext` is `//Home//Sai`, and the second parameter is `Krishna`. That obviously won't work.

Enclose the parameters in quotes:

```
os.system("pdftotext '%s' '%s'" % (input1, output))
```

Comment: And That didn't Work @Tim Pietzcker

Comment: "Didn't work" is not really helpful. What exactly were the results when you used that command? I'm not a Unix person, but are there really supposed to be double slashes in paths? What happens if you type `pdftotext '//Home//Sai Krishna Dubagunta.pdf' '//Home//Me.txt'` in the directory that you're running the Python script in?

Comment: Double slashes is specifying a single slash in the input string. same as in C to print or to specify / we use //. The result is 1. That means according to the Error Codes, it is Invalid Function.

Comment: @Krishna: Are you sure you're not confusing slashes `"/"` and backslashes `"\"`?

Comment: Confused. Always had a problem with that.

Comment: Best to use rawstring `r''` so you don't need to escape backslashes: `r'/Home/Me'`@TimPietzcker et al: since 1995, Windows has accepted '/' as equivalent to `\`

Comment: Anyway it's better to use the Python wrapper to `pdftotext` as @MartinThoma shows.

Answer (score 13):

There are various Python packages to extract the text from a PDF with Python. You can see [a speed/quality benchmark](https://github.com/py-pdf/benchmarks).

As the maintainer of `pypdf` and `PyPDF2` I am biased, but I would recommend `pypdf` for people to start. It's pure-python and a BSD 3-clause license. That should work for most people. Also pypdf can do way more with PDF files (e.g. transformations).

If you feel comfortable with the C-dependency and don't want to modify the PDF, give [pypdfium2](https://pypi.org/project/pypdfium2/) a shot. pypdfium2 is really fast and has an amazing extraction quality.

I previously recommended popplers pdftotext. Don't use that. It's quality is worse than PDFium/PyPDF2.

Tika and PyMuPDF work similarly well as PDFium, but they also have the non-python dependency. PyMuPDF might not work for you due to the commercial license.

I would NOT use pdfminer / pdfminer.six / pdfplumber/ pdftotext / borb / PyPDF2 / PyPDF3 / PyPDF4.

### pypdf: Pure Python

Installation: `pip install pypdf` ([more instructions](https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/installation.html))

```py
from pypdf import PdfReader

reader = PdfReader("example.pdf")
text = ""
for page in reader.pages:
    text += page.extract_text() + "\n"
```

### PDFium: High quality and very fast, but with C-dependency

Installation: `pip install pypdfium2`

```py
import pypdfium2 as pdfium

text = ""
pdf = pdfium.PdfDocument(data)
for i in range(len(pdf)):
    page = pdf.get_page(i)
    textpage = page.get_textpage()
    text += textpage.get_text_range()
    text += "\n"
    [g.close() for g in (textpage, page)]
pdf.close()
```

Comment: This is the best answer. FYI, `pdftotext` requires you [first install `poppler`, which is a little painful on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45912641/unable-to-install-pdftotext-on-python-3-6-missing-poppler)

Comment: I tried PyMuPDF and worked perfectly without any license

Comment: Every software you use has a license.

Comment: @TomásGomezPizarro PyMuPDF is AGPLv3. Simply speaking, this means you are forbidden to use it in a closed source (rsp. not freely licensed) public project. This is legally binding (case law exists). For uses that don't comply with the AGPL, you have to buy a license from Artifex.

Answer (score -1):

I think pdftotext command takes only one argument. Try using:

```
os.system(("pdftotext %s") % input1)
```

and see what happens. Hope this helps.

Comment: Then Where does the output come? I have to give a output path right ? some place to store the file. And the same output. Sorry.

Comment: I came across your question while searching for some info on pdf automation (testing). I based my remark on this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pdftotext where it is mentioned:        $ pdftotext file.pdf               

This usage produces a text file with the same name as the input file. Wildcards (*), for example $ pdftotext *pdf, for converting multiple files, cannot be used because pdftotext expects only one file name.                                                          I could have misunderstood the question.

Comment: I missed out a package that must be installed according to an user in another forum. [link](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/500078-convert-pdf-files-txt-files) But I couldn't try as I don't know how to install that package. I'll try it using PyCharm