# Anaconda - UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict

Tags: python, anaconda, pymc

When I was trying to install a module 'pymc' through anaconda environments, it showed the error message as follows:

> UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in
> conflict:
>
> - blaze -> pyyaml -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0'] -> vc=9
> - blaze -> pyyaml -> yaml -> *[track_features=vc9]
> - pymc Use "conda info " to see the dependencies for each package.

I am using Python 2.7.14, and I installed anaconda 1.6.9 on a Windows. I am new to Python. I first tried to use cmd to install the module pymc and I ran into a lot of problems such as the requirement for install g77 compiler on windows. After I got the compiler from MinGW and also installed the Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python, I still cannot install the module because there came new errors. That is when I found there is pymc module listed in anaconda environment that I can add manually, but it showed this conflict error.

I do not know whether the conflict comes from all those other stuff I installed above or not. Please HELP! Thanks!

Comment: Why do use Python 2.7? This is old and called legacy Python. Better use Python 3.6. This may help you to solve your problem too.

Comment: I use 2.7 because I need to use a module that may not work for Python 3.4.

Comment: Nice to use `mamba` and install all at once https://stackoverflow.com/a/69137255/13697228

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Create a new conda environment for Python 2.7:

```
conda create -n my_pymc_env python=2.7
```

Activate it:

```
conda activate my_pymc_env
```

Alternatively, for older conda versions on Windows:

```
activate my_pymc_env
```

on Unix (including Mac OS X):

```
source activate my_pymc_env
```

Once activated, install your packages:

```
conda install pymc blaze
```

If you still get this message, install the Anaconda client:

```
conda install anaconda-client
```

and search for your package:

```
anaconda search mypackage
```

Look for a channel that has the right version for you and install:

```
conda install -c channel_with_right_version mypackage
```

Comment: After activating the new environment, it seems that I cannot use the modules from the new environment if I stayed in the default environment. Is there any way I can use pymc module from my_pymc_env and still stay in the default environment?

Comment: The whole purpose of environments is isolation. So you would need to work against what `conda` tries to achieve.

Comment: I made the pymc module in the new environment accessible in my default environment by adding the directory of the site-packages in my_pymc_env to the PYTHONPATH manager. The directory looks like C:/Users/*******/AppData/Local/Continnum/anaconda2/envs/my_pymc_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages