# Keras installation error for Anaconda unsatisfiederror

Tags: python, keras, anaconda, spyder

I am getting the following error when I try to install keras for anaconda and use it in python. Can someone help?

```
(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>conda install -c conda-forge keras
Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - anaconda==2018.12=py37_0 -> bleach==3.0.2=py37_0
  - anaconda==2018.12=py37_0 -> numexpr==2.6.8=py37hdce8814_0
  - anaconda==2018.12=py37_0 -> scikit-learn==0.20.1=py37h343c172_0
  - keras
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

[image: thon]

Comment: you need to have the right version of the dependencies. Create a new conda environment, activate and install again. Make sure you have all the right version of the same.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you explain further? I am new to this.

Comment: I found this and trying it now! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42075581/conda-install-python-3-6-unsatisfiableerror

Comment: Nice. You can use this post too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48589141/anaconda-unsatisfiableerror-the-following-specifications-were-found-to-be-in#48594778

Comment: This solved my problem "conda install python=3.5" an then restart pc and then "conda install -c conda-forge keras"

Comment: You can answer your own question then. :)

Comment: Hhahaha. Thank you!