# Error updating Anaconda: UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict

Tags: python, anaconda

When I try to run `conda update --all` Anaconda hangs on solving environment. Based on [this](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8197) Github issue and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48589141/anaconda-unsatisfiableerror-the-following-specifications-were-found-to-be-in) answer in SO, I've tried using:

```
conda update --all --override-channels -c conda-forge
```

But each time I try that I get this error:

```
Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - navigator-updater
  - pycurl
```

Except **with a different set of packages each time**, and without specified versions, as seems to be the case with most SO questions about this error.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Please add you're `conda info`.

Comment: Thanks @merv, I think I've found the explanation now: https://www.anaconda.com/why-we-removed-the-free-channel-in-conda-4-7/

Comment: Seems to be an issue with the new version of conda: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8954 - I have now given up and just created a new environment with the same packages

Comment: I doubt it. Just seems like you probably have many packages originally from `anaconda` channel, but now you're trying to force everything to source from Conda Forge, but it doesn't have all those and it leads to conflicts.