# Conda wont install pdfplumber

Tags: python, conda, pdfplumber

I'm trying to use miniconda3 to install pdfplumber. I keep getting this error message and I don't know how to interpret it.

```
(env1) C:\Users\engineer>conda install -c conda-forge pdfplumber
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: -
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions
Note that strict channel priority may have removed packages required for satisfiability.
```

Also:

```
(env1) C:\Users\engineer>conda info

 active environment : env1
active env location : C:\tools\miniconda3\envs\env1
        shell level : 2
   user config file : C:\Users\engineer\.condarc  populated config files : C:\Users\engineer\.condarc
      conda version : 4.10.3
conda-build version : not installed
     python version : 3.8.10.final.0
   virtual packages : __cuda=10.2=0
                      __win=0=0
                      __archspec=1=x86_64
   base environment : C:\tools\miniconda3  (writable)
  conda av data dir : C:\tools\miniconda3\etc\conda   conda av metadata url : None
       channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
                      https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
      package cache : C:\tools\miniconda3\pkgs
                      C:\Users\engineer\.conda\pkgs
                      C:\Users\engineer\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
   envs directories : C:\tools\miniconda3\envs
                      C:\Users\engineer\.conda\envs
                      C:\Users\engineer\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
           platform : win-64
         user-agent : conda/4.10.3 requests/2.26.0 CPython/3.8.10 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.18363
      administrator : False
         netrc file : None
       offline mode : False
```

Using pip is not an option as it absolutely will not work behind my corporate proxy whereas miniconda3 will.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## No ImageMagick for win-64

Another case of Conda being terrible at identifying unsatisfiability issues. [Mamba](https://github.com/mamba-org/mamba#readme) does just fine with this, identifying that the `imagemagick` package is not available for the **win-64** platform:

```bash
$ CONDA_SUBDIR="win-64" mamba create -dn foo -c conda-forge pdfplumber

                  __    __    __    __
                 /  \  /  \  /  \  /  \
                /    \/    \/    \/    \
███████████████/  /██/  /██/  /██/  /████████████████████████
              /  / \   / \   / \   / \  \____
             /  /   \_/   \_/   \_/   \    o \__,
            / _/                       \_____/  `
            |/
        ███╗   ███╗ █████╗ ███╗   ███╗██████╗  █████╗
        ████╗ ████║██╔══██╗████╗ ████║██╔══██╗██╔══██╗
        ██╔████╔██║███████║██╔████╔██║██████╔╝███████║
        ██║╚██╔╝██║██╔══██║██║╚██╔╝██║██╔══██╗██╔══██║
        ██║ ╚═╝ ██║██║  ██║██║ ╚═╝ ██║██████╔╝██║  ██║
        ╚═╝     ╚═╝╚═╝  ╚═╝╚═╝     ╚═╝╚═════╝ ╚═╝  ╚═╝

        mamba (0.15.2) supported by @QuantStack

        GitHub:  https://github.com/mamba-org/mamba
        Twitter: https://twitter.com/QuantStack

█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████


Looking for: ['pdfplumber']

bioconda/win-64          [====================] (00m:00s) No change
pkgs/main/noarch         [====================] (00m:00s) Done
pkgs/r/win-64            [====================] (00m:00s) Done
pkgs/r/noarch            [====================] (00m:00s) No change
pkgs/main/win-64         [====================] (00m:00s) Done
bioconda/noarch          [====================] (00m:01s) Done
conda-forge/noarch       [====================] (00m:01s) Done
conda-forge/win-64       [====================] (00m:02s) Done
Encountered problems while solving:
  - nothing provides imagemagick needed by wand-0.5.6-py_0
```

## Possible Workaround

It should work to install ImageMagick natively on your system, and ensure that it is accessible from the command line. Then you could create an environment with a force-installed `wand` package, the only package that depends on ImageMagick.

Here are the steps to create the environment (called `my_env` below but name it as you wish):

```bash
## create the environment with python (I think you can use 3.6+)
conda create -n my_env python=3.9

## force-install "wand"
conda install -n my_env --no-deps wand=0.6.5

## install pdfplumber
conda install -n my_env pdfplumber

## try using the environment
conda activate my_env
```

#### Additional Notes

**Don't need ImageMagick.** Technically, ImageMagick only seems to be used for [the "Visual Debugging" functionality of pdfplumber](https://github.com/jsvine/pdfplumber#visual-debugging). If you don't need that, then you can forego installing ImageMagick altogether. I verified (on **osx-64**) that the above environment without ImageMagick could run both the CLI example and the first Python API example from the pdfplumber docs.

**Use isolated environment.** Because force-installs can be dangerous (read the `conda install --help` on the `--no-deps` flag), I strongly recommend creating a dedicated environment for this, as shown above.

**Why pin the `wand` version?** I specified a version for `wand` because that will help prevent Conda from trying to change it in the future when updating.

**Mamba is awesome.** I highly recommend using Mamba. It's a simple install:

```bash
conda install -n base -c conda-forge mamba
```

then just use `mamba` whenever you would normally type `conda` (the exception being the `conda activate` and `conda deactivate` commands).