# failed to install tensorflow with a lot of package conflicts

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to install tensorflow in one of my conda enviroment. and I got a lot of conflicts and eventually failed to install tensorflow.

But I need to keep this enviroment and add tensorflow, is there a way to fix this?  Thanks

I do use 64bit python and I use conda install tensorflow. Thank you!

```
Examining intervaltree:  78%|███████████████████████████████████████████▋            | 181/232 [01:12<00:09,  5.29it/s]\Examining qstylizer:  79%|██████████████████████████████████████████████▊            | 184/232 [01:13<00:18,  2.64it/s]|Examining chardet:  84%|███████████████████████████████████████████████████▎         | 195/232 [01:16<00:15,  2.38it/s]\Examining jupyter_core:  91%|███████████████████████████████████████████████████▏    | 212/232 [01:24<00:14,  1.41it/s]\Examining m2w64-gcc-libs-core:  95%|██████████████████████████████████████████████▍  | 220/232 [01:31<00:08,  1.49it/s]-Examining python-cufflinks:  97%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████▍ | 225/232 [01:32<00:02,  2.70it/s]\                                                                                                                       |Examining conflict for babel jupyterlab-plotly-extension certifi markupsafe mistune pyflakes python-slugify traitlets c-Examining conflict for pandas-datareader babel sphinx jupyterlab_server python-cufflinks matplotlib pytz chart-studio p-Examining conflict for babel jupyterlab-plotly-extension pywin32-ctypes certifi markupsafe mistune pyflakes python-slug|Examining conflict for jupyterlab-plotly-extension jupyterlab_server jupyterlab:   7%| | 16/232 [02:23<27:22,  7.60s/it/Examining conflict for jupyterlab-plotly-extension jupyterlab spyder-kernels python-cufflinks ipykernel ipython jupyter|
```

after that,

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

Package pyopenssl conflicts for:
requests -> urllib3[version='>=1.21.1,<1.27'] -> pyopenssl[version='>=0.14']
pyopenssl
prometheus_client -> twisted -> pyopenssl[version='>=16.0.0']
urllib3 -> pyopenssl[version='>=0.14']

Package icc_rt conflicts for:
mkl_random -> numpy[version='>=1.16,<2.0a0'] -> icc_rt[version='>=13.1.6|>=2019.0.0|>=16.0.4']
ta -> numpy -> icc_rt[version='>=13.1.6|>=2019.0.0|>=16.0.4']
statsmodels -> scipy[version='>=1.3'] -> icc_rt[version='>=13.1.6|>=2019.0.0|>=16.0.4']
python-cufflinks -> numpy[version='>=1.9.2'] -> icc_rt[version='>=13.1.6|>=2019.0.0|>=16.0.4']
numpy -> icc_rt[version='>=13.1.6|>=2019.0.0|>=16.0.4']
numpy-base -> icc_rt[version='>=13.1.6|>=2019.0.0|>=16.0.4']
matplotlib-base -> numpy[version='>=1.16.6,<2.0a0'] -> icc_rt[version='>=13.1.6|>=2019.0.0|>=16.0.4']
patsy -> numpy[version='>=1.4.0'] -> icc_rt[version='>=13.1.6|>=2019.0.0|>=16.0.4']
matplotlib -> numpy[version='>=1.14.6,<2.0a0'] -> icc_rt[version='>=13.1.6|>=2019.0.0|>=16.0.4']
seaborn -> numpy[version='>=1.15'] -> icc_rt[version='>=13.1.6|>=2019.0.0|>=16.0.4']
pandas -> numpy[version='>=1.16.6,<2.0a0'] -> icc_rt[version='>=13.1.6|>=2019.0.0|>=16.0.4']
scipy -> icc_rt[version='>=13.1.6|>=2019.0.0|>=16.0.4']
```

Comment: Take a look at this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69754812/conda-unsatisfiableerror-even-when-seemingly-there-isnt-any-conflict 
In your case I also can't see any conflict, conda is not very helpful with the output. Try to make a minimal reproducible environment.yml file

Comment: Please  create  a fresh conda environment  and Run "conda install tensorflow " to see the difference. But I suggest to follow instruction from here and make sure your pip version is updated. https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip

Comment: Is this a fresh environment? What other packages do you have installed? These issues are dependency issues because a package that's already installed also installed specific versions of some dependencies. The new package you want to install wants to install other versions of these same dependencies. Hence, the conflict. Confusing, I know. You will need to install an older or newer version of one of the packages.