# why it is so difficult to make tensorflow work?

Tags: python, tensorflow, installation

Over the years, I always stumbled with the installation of tensorflow. I really love this library but at the same time, I also really hate it because it is so difficult to make it work. I can install it but I always have an error when running it. Can anyone make it easy to install and make it work considering it is so popular?

I spend almost the whole day today figuring out the installation issue with tensorflow. This morning I got a conflict issue with scipy, DLL stuff which I posted it twice already from last night.

[failed to install tensorflow with a lot of package conflicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70874108/failed-to-install-tensorflow-with-a-lot-of-package-conflicts)

[statsmodels: ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _arpack: The specified procedure could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70883720/statsmodels-importerror-dll-load-failed-while-importing-arpack-the-specified)

I eventually decided to start from scratch and create new environments with python 3.6.10 and then installed tensorflow first, then added matplotlib, pandas, statsmodels, etc.  I am still stuck now

```
File "C:\Users\test\miniconda3\envs\dash36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_core.estimator'
```

then I tried to print a version of tensorflow-estimator to see conflict. and I got another error.

```
>>> import tensorflow-estimator
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    import tensorflow-estimator
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

can anyone please help me with the installation of tensorflow? could you please tell me which python version, tensorflow version, numpy/scipy version, scikit-learn version? I am going to work with plotly dash. which dash version also works with tensorflow?

Thank you so much

Comment: Note that `tensorflow-estimator` can not be the name of a python module because it contains a dash and can therefore not be an identifier, much like you can not write `foo-bar = 42`.

Comment: Thanks SebDieBin, then can I do this: import tensorflow_estimator, then I got an error of ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_core.estimator

Comment: There is a post related to `tensorflow-estimator`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66022256/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-tensorflow-core-estimator-for-tensorflow But my suggestion is, if you gonna install tensorflow, always do it in a new environment. If it still not working, you can try using colab.

Comment: Thanks Jason, for tensorflow 2.4 or higher, which python version is compatible? 3.7 or 3.8?

Comment: Have you considered using a ready to use Docker image with TF installed? https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow/

Comment: I think getting Tensorflow to work with a GPU is the most difficult thing I have done in all of computer science. Am now on hour 19 and still trying to install tensorflow with CUDA, nothing works as described, and the tutorials are all really bad and even contradicting ..

Answer (score 1):

Try creating new virtual environment using Python and install Tensorflow.

```
#Create virtual env called venv
python -m venv --system-site-packages .\venv
#Activate venv
.\venv\Scripts\activate
#Upgrade pip
pip install --upgrade pip
#Install latest Tensorflow version: Current latest version 2.8
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
#Verify the install:
python -c "import tensorflow as"
```

Comment: Thanks TFer, how to do it using annaconda?