# not able to Install an old version of tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, conda

How can I install an old version of Tensorflow in conda vertual environnement? I want Tensorflow-gpu 1.4, when I attempt this command:

```bash
conda install tensorflow-gpu=1.4
```

I see the message in attached picture.

[image]

When I tried `conda create -n tf_1_4 python=3.6 tensorflow-gpu=1.4` and I got this :

```bash
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: \
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

Package python conflicts for:
python=3.6
tensorflow-gpu=1.4 -> tensorflow-gpu-base==1.4.1 -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0']

The following specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:

 - feature:/linux-64::__glibc==2.26=0
 - feature:|@/linux-64::__glibc==2.26=0

Your installed version is: 2.26
```

Comment: maybe try it with Mamba - I find it gives more precision diagnostic feedback. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69137255/570918

Answer (score 0):

The error message states that Python must be either 2.7, 3.5, or 3.6, whereas the current environment is 3.7. Create a new environment:

```bash
conda create -n tf_1_4 python=3.6 tensorflow-gpu=1.4
```

Comment: failed
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:
Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions
Package python conflicts for:
python=3.6
tensorflow-gpu=1.4 -> tensorflow-gpu-base==1.4.1 -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0']The following specifications were found to be incompatible with your system: feature:/linux-64::__glibc==2.26=0 feature:|@/linux-64::__glibc==2.26=0
Your installed version is: 2.26'

Comment: @rif3aadev try adding both conda-forge and the free channel `conda create -n tf_1_4 -c conda-forge -c free tensorflow-gpu=1.4 python=3.6`