# UnsatisfiableError when installing cuml

Tags: python, conda, rapids

I am installing cuml using conda

`conda install -c rapidsai cuml=21.12`

This is the trace I get:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: /
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versionsThe following specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:

  - feature:/linux-64::__glibc==2.31=0
  - cuml=21.12 -> cupy[version='>=7.8.0,<10.0.0a0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17|>=2.17,<3.0.a0']
  - python=3.8 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.5.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']

Your installed version is: 2.31
```

My confusion is that it's saying I need a __glibc version of greater than 2.17 but I have an installed version of 2.31.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring [Conda's poor conflict reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69137255/570918), RAPIDS has very specific channel specification (`rapidsai > nvidia > conda-forge`), so that could be affecting the solving. It might be sufficient to include those channels:

```bash
conda install -c rapidsai -c nvidia -c conda-forge cuml=21.12
```

However, it could also be the case that something previously installed is preventing correct installation. Moreover, when packages require specialized channels it is generally better practice to create a dedicated environment:

```bash
conda create -n cuml -c rapidsai -c nvidia -c conda-forge cuml=21.12
```

This latter is similar to what [the RAPIDS installation selector](https://rapids.ai/start.html#get-rapids) generates.

Comment: Thanks, I got the same error even with including the additional channels but I was able to work around the problem by creating a dedicated environment and installing RAPIDS first before the other required packages.

Answer (score 0):

Besides trying, this

```
conda create -n cuml -c rapidsai -c nvidia -c conda-forge cuml=21.12
```

from the previous post of @merv, just try that:

```
conda create -n cuml -c rapidsai -c nvidia -c conda-forge cuml
```

should solve the problem.

Comment: also, building on this, try using `mamba` instead of `conda`