# Spyder not launching in environment

Tags: python, pip, conda, spyder

I have an evironment set up for [QCoDeS](https://qcodes.github.io/Qcodes/)

But when I try & install Spyder using `conda install`, it keeps freezing up even after updating `conda`. I've tried installing through Navigator but it complains about the Python version (3.10) & doesn't install.

I found a suggestion that installing `Spyder` with `pip install spyder` should do the job (yes I know conflicts but I'm running out of options)

Spyder installs and shows up in the list of installed packages but isn't recognized when I enter `spyder` at the `conda` command line (W10 x64).

What's going on here? I'm at a loss, should I downgrade the Python version in my environment (how do?)? Is that going to mess with `QcoDeS` the reason for the envirornment in the first place?

EDIT:: Solution, as mentioned below there are no `python 3.10` builds for Spyder so, I deleted the environment & recreated using `conda create -n qcodes python=3.9`. Spyder now installs & runs in the environment & `qcodes` happily runs with `python 3.9`.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing yet provides Python 3.10 builds for Spyder, however, Conda Forge does offer `spyder-kernels` builds for 3.10. This would entail creating a separate environment dedicated to hosting only the Spyder infrastructure, and then installing `spyder-kernels` in the environments you wish to use in Spyder.

That is, something like

```bash
## install spyder-kernels in the env of interest
conda install -n myenv -c conda-forge spyder-kernels

## create dedicated env for spyder
conda create -n spyder spyder

## always launch spyder from that env
conda activate spyder
spyder

## switch kernels from GUI
```

Then follow [Spyder documentation](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder) to switch to the kernel of interest.

Comment: Unfortunately the evironment wont solve (frozen or flexible) & then I'm told the packages aren't available from the `conda-forge` channel

Comment: Which one of the two environments doesn't solve? `myenv` or `spyder`?

Comment: @DrBwts if you'd like better resolution on *why* it fails, I've found [`mamba` can help with that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62288835/570918).

Comment: @CarlosCordoba `myenv` when I try `conda install -n myenv -c conda-forge spyder-kernels`

Comment: What if you simply run `conda install -n myenv spyder-kernels`?

Comment: @DrBwts without including more details in the question (list packages in environment, show `conda info`, show output of running `conda install ...`), it is difficult to help further.

Comment: recreated the evironment with python 3.9 & its all fine (edited OP)