# Conda build using previously built/deployed package

Tags: anaconda, conda, artifactory, miniconda, conda-build

My current flow is to build **package-a**, then deploy **package-a** to Artifactory. Then I'm building **package-b** pointing at artifactory channels that contain the **package-a** conda package. However, I'm getting **a lot** (hundreds) of dependency conflicts when I build `package-b`. Am I doing this flow correct?

Below are my meta.yaml's

**package-a**

```
{% set data = load_setup_py_data() %}

package:
  name: "package-a"
  version: {{ data.get('version') }}

build:
  noarch: generic
  script: python setup.py install --single-version-externally-managed --record=record.txt

source:
  path: ..

requirements:
  run:
    - python 3.6
    - aiohttp-swagger
    - elasticsearch-dsl
    - aiocache
    - aiohttp
    - aioredis
    - arrow

  build:
    - python 3.6
```

**package-b**

```
{% set data = load_setup_py_data() %}

package:
  name: "package-b"
  version: {{ data.get('version') }}

build:
  noarch: generic
  script: python setup.py install --single-version-externally-managed --record=record.txt

source:
  path: ..

requirements:
  run:
    - python 3.6
    - albumentations
    - package-a
    - pillow
    - rasterio
    - shapely-geojson
    - scikit-image
    - scikit-learn

  build:
    - python 3.6
```

**Note: That I'm installing package-a (from artifactory) into package-b.**

Sample of error output

```
Package ca-certificates conflicts for:
python=3.6 -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1l,<1.1.2a'] -> ca-certificates
scikit-learn -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0'] -> ca-certificates
keras -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0'] -> ca-certificates
geojson -> python -> ca-certificates
shapely -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0'] -> ca-certificates
noise -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0'] -> ca-certificates
pillow -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0'] -> ca-certificates
scikit-image -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0'] -> ca-certificates
tqdm -> python[version='>=2.7'] -> ca-certificates
shapely-geojson -> python -> ca-certificates
rasterio -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0'] -> ca-certificates
opencv[version='<=4.5.3'] -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0'] -> ca-certificates
albumentations -> python -> ca-certificates
...
...
...
```

Comment: Could you try doing it with Mamba instead? Conda’s conflict reporting is very imprecise. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69137255/570918

Comment: BTW, if the error is from solving *during* the build process, install the `conda-forge::boa` package. That provides `conda mambabuild` as a drop-in replacement for `conda build`, and uses `mamba` for any of the solve steps in the build process.

Comment: The errors are during the build process, I'm trying `mamba build` now. Should I use `conda mambabuild`

Comment: @merv looks like mamba build worked 100%, without any conflicts to resolve. Crazy that it works that much better.

Comment: Well, that's a bonus! I was only expecting you'd get a more precise error message. Mamba does use a different solver, so maybe you were hitting a bug in the Conda solver - not sure.