# Conda reports conflicts but there seems to be no conflict

Tags: python, conda, glibc

I've been struggling to update `pyqt` to a newest version, but it failed with package conflict. (the package I tried to update seems irrelevant here)

As it is evident from the following message I've attached in the end, `glibc` has version 2.35 installed. All the packages require `glibc` version 2.17 or later. So there is no conflict, but it refuses to install.

So, what would be the reason for this error, and what would I have to do to force update?

```
The following specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:

  - feature:/linux-64::__glibc==2.35=0
  - feature:|@/linux-64::__glibc==2.35=0
  - argon2-cffi -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - argon2-cffi-bindings -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.5.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - armadillo -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - arpack -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - astropy -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - astropy-healpix -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.5.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - astroscrappy -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - blas -> libgfortran-ng -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - blosc -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - brotli -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - brotli-bin -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - brotlipy -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - brunsli -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - bzip2 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - c-ares -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - c-blosc2 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - cairo -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - cffi -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - cfitsio -> libgfortran-ng -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - cftime -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - charls -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - conda-package-handling -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - cramjam -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - cryptography -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - curl -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - cython -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - cytoolz -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - dbus -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - expat -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - fastparquet -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - fitsio -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - fontconfig -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - freetype -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - george -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - geos -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - giflib -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.5.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - glib -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - gpy -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - gst-plugins-base -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - gstreamer -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - h5py -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - hdf4 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - hdf5 -> libgfortran-ng -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - icu -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.5.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - imagecodecs -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - jbig -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - jpeg -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.5.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - jxrlib -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - kiwisolver -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - krb5 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - lazy-object-proxy -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - lcms2 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - lerc -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - libaec -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - libblas -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - libboost -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - libbrotlicommon -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - libbrotlidec -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - libbrotlienc -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - libcblas -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - libcurl -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - libdeflate -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - libedit -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.5.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - libev -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.5.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - libffi -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.5.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - libgcc-ng -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - libgfortran-ng -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - liblapack -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - liblapacke -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - libllvm10 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.5.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - libnetcdf -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - libnghttp2 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - libopenblas -> libgfortran-ng -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - libpng -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.5.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - libsodium -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.5.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - libssh2 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - libstdcxx-ng -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - libtiff -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - libuuid -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - libwebp -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - libwebp-base -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - libxcb -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - libxml2 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - libzip -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - libzlib -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.5.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - libzopfli -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - llvm-openmp -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - llvmlite -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - lz4-c -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - markupsafe -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - matplotlib -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - matplotlib-base -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - mistune -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - mpi4py -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - mpich -> libgfortran-ng -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - msgpack-python -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - ncurses -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.5.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - netcdf4 -> openssh -> __glibc[version='>=2.17|>=2.17,<3.0.a0']
  - numba -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - numcodecs -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - numexpr -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - numpy -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - openblas -> libgfortran-ng -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - openjpeg -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - openssl -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - pandas -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - pcre -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - pillow -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - pixman -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.5.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - proj -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - psutil -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - pthread-stubs -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.5.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - py-boost -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - pycosat -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - pyproj -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - pyqt5-sip -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - pyqt=5.12.3 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.5.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - pyregion -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - pyrsistent -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - python=3.8 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - pywavelets -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - pyyaml -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - pyzmq -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - qt -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - readline -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - regex -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - regions -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - reproject -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - ruamel_yaml -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - scikit-image -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - scikit-learn -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - scipy -> libgfortran-ng -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - sep -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - shapely -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - sip -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - snappy -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.5.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - sqlite -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - statsmodels -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - superlu -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - swig -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - tifffile -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - tk -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.5.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - tornado -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - ujson -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - unicodedata2 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.5.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - wrapt -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - xorg-kbproto -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - xorg-libice -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - xorg-libsm -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - xorg-libx11 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - xorg-libxau -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - xorg-libxdmcp -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - xorg-libxext -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - xorg-libxrender -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - xorg-renderproto -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - xorg-xextproto -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - xorg-xproto -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - xz -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.5.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - yaml -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.5.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - zeromq -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - zfp -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - zlib -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.5.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - zstd -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']

Your installed version is: 2.35
```

Comment: Did you try `pip install package --ignore-installed` ?

Comment: @razimbres That could solve it, but I fear that would break current conda dependency. What I heard is, it is generally recommended not to use `pip` when using with `conda`, especially when installing a package that other packages depend...

Comment: Yes, that's a possibility. Python dependencies sometimes are really awful.

Comment: Mamba [often gives better reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69137255/570918) (or enable the new [`conda-libmamba-solver`](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/a-faster-conda-for-a-growing-community)).

Comment: @merv I tried this and it seemed to work to a degree, then in an attempt to solve a conflict it downgraded itself and now I can't call `mamba` because `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conda._vendor.auxlib'`.