# how conda-build avoids checking incompatibility

Tags: python, conda, conda-build

I am building a conda package and use the command `conda-build xxx --python 3.8`. But it always checks the conda environment and finally fails due to package incompatibility. Is there anyone knowing how I can avoid this step of checking incompatibility? Thanks.

```
>conda-build xxx --python 3.8
No numpy version specified in conda_build_config.yaml.  Falling back to default numpy value of 1.16
WARNING:conda_build.metadata:No numpy version specified in conda_build_config.yaml.  Falling back to default numpy value of 1.16
Adding in variants from internal_defaults
INFO:conda_build.variants:Adding in variants from internal_defaults
Adding in variants from config.variant
INFO:conda_build.variants:Adding in variants from config.variant
Attempting to finalize metadata for deepsmirud
INFO:conda_build.metadata:Attempting to finalize metadata for deepsmirud
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): conda.anaconda.org:443
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://conda.anaconda.org:443 "GET /t/Ji-ed938dc0-e7a3-4757-84b4-3ade97e13fb1/conda-forge/win-64/repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://conda.anaconda.org:443 "GET /t/Ji-ed938dc0-e7a3-4757-84b4-3ade97e13fb1/conda-forge/noarch/repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://conda.anaconda.org:443 "GET /t/Ji-ed938dc0-e7a3-4757-84b4-3ade97e13fb1/bioconda/win-64/repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://conda.anaconda.org:443 "GET /t/Ji-ed938dc0-e7a3-4757-84b4-3ade97e13fb1/bioconda/noarch/repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://conda.anaconda.org:443 "GET /t/Ji-ed938dc0-e7a3-4757-84b4-3ade97e13fb1/r/win-64/repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://conda.anaconda.org:443 "GET /t/Ji-ed938dc0-e7a3-4757-84b4-3ade97e13fb1/r/noarch/repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): repo.anaconda.com:443
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://repo.anaconda.com:443 "GET /pkgs/main/win-64/repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://repo.anaconda.com:443 "GET /pkgs/main/noarch/repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://repo.anaconda.com:443 "GET /pkgs/r/win-64/repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://repo.anaconda.com:443 "GET /pkgs/r/noarch/repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://repo.anaconda.com:443 "GET /pkgs/msys2/win-64/repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://repo.anaconda.com:443 "GET /pkgs/msys2/noarch/repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://conda.anaconda.org:443 "GET /t/Ji-ed938dc0-e7a3-4757-84b4-3ade97e13fb1/r/win-64 HTTP/1.1" 302 None
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://conda.anaconda.org:443 "GET /r/win-64/ HTTP/1.1" 200 None
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://repo.anaconda.com:443 "GET /pkgs/msys2/channeldata.json HTTP/1.1" 200 None
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://repo.anaconda.com:443 "GET /pkgs/r/channeldata.json HTTP/1.1" 200 None
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://conda.anaconda.org:443 "GET /t/Ji-ed938dc0-e7a3-4757-84b4-3ade97e13fb1/conda-forge/win-64 HTTP/1.1" 302 None
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://conda.anaconda.org:443 "GET /conda-forge/win-64/ HTTP/1.1" 200 None
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://conda.anaconda.org:443 "GET /t/Ji-ed938dc0-e7a3-4757-84b4-3ade97e13fb1/bioconda/win-64 HTTP/1.1" 302 None
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://conda.anaconda.org:443 "GET /bioconda/win-64/ HTTP/1.1" 200 None
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://repo.anaconda.com:443 "GET /pkgs/main/channeldata.json HTTP/1.1" 200 None
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... WARNING conda.models.version:get_matcher(541): Using .* with relational operator is superfluous and deprecated and will be removed in a future version of conda. Your spec was 1.*, but conda is ignoring the .* and treating it as 1
WARNING conda.models.version:get_matcher(541): Using .* with relational operator is superfluous and deprecated and will be removed in a future version of conda.
Your spec was 2.*, but conda is ignoring the .* and treating it as 2
WARNING conda.models.version:get_matcher(541): Using .* with relational operator is superfluous and deprecated and will be removed in a future version of conda.
Your spec was 3.*, but conda is ignoring the .* and treating it as 3
WARNING conda.models.version:get_matcher(541): Using .* with relational operator is superfluous and deprecated and will be removed in a future version of conda.
Your spec was 0.23.*, but conda is ignoring the .* and treating it as 0.23
WARNING conda.models.version:get_matcher(541): Using .* with relational operator is superfluous and deprecated and will be removed in a future version of conda.
Your spec was 3.*, but conda is ignoring the .* and treating it as 3
WARNING conda.models.version:get_matcher(541): Using .* with relational operator is superfluous and deprecated and will be removed in a future version of conda.
Your spec was 2.*, but conda is ignoring the .* and treating it as 2
WARNING conda.models.version:get_matcher(541): Using .* with relational operator is superfluous and deprecated and will be removed in a future version of conda.
Your spec was 3.6.*, but conda is ignoring the .* and treating it as 3.6
WARNING conda.models.version:get_matcher(541): Using .* with relational operator is superfluous and deprecated and will be removed in a future version of conda.
Your spec was 4.*, but conda is ignoring the .* and treating it as 4

Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed

Leaving build/test directories:
  Work:
 D:\Programming\anaconda3\envs\tf2\conda-bld\work
  Test:
 D:\Programming\anaconda3\envs\tf2\conda-bld\test_tmp
Leaving build/test environments:
  Test:
source activate  D:\Programming\anaconda3\envs\tf2\conda-bld\_test_env
  Build:
source activate  D:\Programming\anaconda3\envs\tf2\conda-bld\_build_env


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programming\anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\conda_build\environ.py", line 799, in get_install_actions
    actions = install_actions(prefix, index, specs, force=True)
  File "D:\Programming\anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\conda\common\io.py", line 86, in decorated
    return f(*args, **kwds)
  File "D:\Programming\anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\conda\plan.py", line 473, in install_actions
    txn = solver.solve_for_transaction(prune=prune, ignore_pinned=not pinned)
  File "D:\Programming\anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 155, in solve_for_transaction
    should_retry_solve)
  File "D:\Programming\anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 196, in solve_for_diff
    force_remove, should_retry_solve)
  File "D:\Programming\anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 319, in solve_final_state
    ssc = self._run_sat(ssc)
  File "D:\Programming\anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\conda\common\io.py", line 86, in decorated
    return f(*args, **kwds)
  File "D:\Programming\anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 856, in _run_sat
    should_retry_solve=ssc.should_retry_solve
  File "D:\Programming\anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\conda\common\io.py", line 86, in decorated
    return f(*args, **kwds)
  File "D:\Programming\anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\conda\resolve.py", line 1323, in solve
    self.find_conflicts(specs, specs_to_add, history_specs)
  File "D:\Programming\anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\conda\resolve.py", line 352, in find_conflicts
    raise UnsatisfiableError(bad_deps, strict=strict_channel_priority)
conda.exceptions.UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

Package expat conflicts for:
python=3.8 -> pypy3.8=7.3.9 -> expat[version='>=2.4.7,<3.0a0|>=2.4.8,<3.0a0']
click==8.1.3 -> pypy3.9[version='>=7.3.9'] -> expat[version='>=2.4.8,<3.0a0']
numpy==1.19.5 -> pypy3.9[version='>=7.3.8'] -> expat[version='>=2.4.1,<3.0a0|>=2.4.7,<3.0a0|>=2.4.8,<3.0a0']
pandas==1.3.5 -> pypy3.7[version='>=7.3.7'] -> expat[version='>=2.4.1,<3.0a0']
biopython==1.79 -> pypy3.8[version='>=7.3.9'] -> expat[version='>=2.4.8,<3.0a0']

Package vs2008_runtime conflicts for:
pip -> python -> vs2008_runtime
rdkit -> python=2.7 -> vs2008_runtime
pyfiglet==0.8.post1 -> python -> vs2008_runtime

Package python conflicts for:
click==8.1.3 -> colorama -> python[version='2.7.*|3.5.*|3.6.*|>=3.6|3.4.*|>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|3.9.*|3.8.*|>=3|3.7.*|3.10.*']
pyfiglet==0.8.post1 -> setuptools -> python[version='2.7.*|3.5.*|3.6.*|>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.10,<3.11.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|3.4.*']
pip -> python[version='2.7.*|3.5.*|3.6.*|>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3|>=3.6|>=3.7|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|3.4.*|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0|>=3.10,<3.11.0a0']
tensorflow==2.6.0 -> python[version='3.7.*|3.8.*|3.9.*']
rdkit -> matplotlib-base -> python[version='3.10.*|3.4.*|>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.7.1,<3.8.0a0|3.9.*|3.7.*|3.8.*']
pip -> wheel -> python[version='!=3.0,!=3.1,!=3.2,!=3.3,!=3.4|2.7.*|>=3.6|2.7|>=3.6|>=2.7|>=3.6,<4.0']
biopython==1.79 -> numpy -> python[version='3.10.*|3.5.*|3.6.*|>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|3.9.*|3.8.*|3.7.*']
rdkit -> python[version='2.7.*|3.5.*|3.6.*|>=3.10,<3.11.0a0|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0']
tensorflow==2.6.0 -> tensorboard[version='>=2.6.0'] -> python[version='>=3.2|>=3.2,<3.10|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0']
pandas==1.3.5 -> numpy[version='>=1.19.5,<2.0a0'] -> python[version='2.7.*|3.5.*|3.6.*|>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.6|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|>=3|3.4.*|3.10.*|3.9.*|3.8.*|3.7.*']
biopython==1.79 -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0']
pandas==1.3.5 -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0']
numpy==1.19.5 -> python_abi=3.9[build=*_cp39] -> python[version='3.6.*|3.7.*|3.9.*|3.8.*']
numpy==1.19.5 -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0']
click==8.1.3 -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0']
pyfiglet==0.8.post1 -> python

Package mkl conflicts for:
biopython==1.79 -> numpy -> mkl[version='>=2018.0.0,<2019.0a0|>=2018.0.1,<2019.0a0|>=2018.0.2,<2019.0a0|>=2018.0.3,<2019.0a0|>=2019.1,<2021.0a0|>=2019.3,<2021.0a0|>=2019.4,<2020.0a0|>=2021.4.0,<2022.0a0|>=2021.3.0,<2022.0a0|>=2021.2.0,<2022.0a0|>=2019.4,<2021.0a0']
pandas==1.3.5 -> numpy[version='>=1.19.5,<2.0a0'] -> mkl[version='>=2019.4,<2021.0a0|>=2021.2.0,<2022.0a0|>=2021.3.0,<2022.0a0|>=2021.4.0,<2022.0a0|>=2022.0.0,<2023.0a0']
numpy==1.19.5 -> libblas[version='>=3.8.0,<4.0a0'] -> mkl[version='2019.1.*|2019.3|2019.4|2020.0|2020.1|2020.2|2020.4|2021.2.0|2021.3.0|2021.4.0|2022.0.0|2022.1.0|>=2020.4,<2021.0a0|>=2020.2,<2021.0a0|>=2019.3,<2020.0a0|>=2019.0,<2020.0a0',build='203|166|hb70f87d_311|h0e2418a_729|h6a75c08_874|h0e2418a_796|hb70f87d_564|hb70f87d_389|hb70f87d_311|256|256|216|245|203']
rdkit -> numpy[version='>=1.21.6,<2.0a0'] -> mkl[version='>=2018.0.0,<2019.0a0|>=2018.0.1,<2019.0a0|>=2018.0.2,<2019.0a0|>=2018.0.3,<2019.0a0|>=2019.1,<2021.0a0|>=2019.3,<2021.0a0|>=2019.4,<2020.0a0|>=2019.4,<2021.0a0|>=2021.2.0,<2022.0a0|>=2021.3.0,<2022.0a0|>=2021.4.0,<2022.0a0']

Package setuptools conflicts for:
pandas==1.3.5 -> numexpr[version='>=2.7.0'] -> setuptools
rdkit -> matplotlib-base -> setuptools[version='<60.0.0']
tensorflow==2.6.0 -> tensorboard[version='>=2.6.0'] -> setuptools[version='>=41.0.0']
python=3.8 -> pip -> setuptools
pandas==1.3.5 -> setuptools[version='<60.0.0']
pip -> setuptools
pyfiglet==0.8.post1 -> setuptools

Package vs2010_runtime conflicts for:
pyfiglet==0.8.post1 -> python -> vs2010_runtime
pip -> python[version='>=3'] -> vs2010_runtime

Package requests conflicts for:
pip -> requests
python=3.8 -> pip -> requests
tensorflow==2.6.0 -> tensorboard[version='>=2.6.0'] -> requests[version='>=2.21.0,<3']

Package m2w64-gcc-libs conflicts for:
numpy==1.19.5 -> libblas[version='>=3.8.0,<4.0a0'] -> m2w64-gcc-libs
rdkit -> pycairo -> m2w64-gcc-libs

Package packaging conflicts for:
pip -> wheel -> packaging[version='>=20.2']
rdkit -> matplotlib-base -> packaging[version='>=20.0']
pandas==1.3.5 -> numexpr[version='>=2.7.0'] -> packaging
pip -> packaging
python=3.8 -> pip -> packaging

Package six conflicts for:
tensorflow==2.6.0 -> tensorboard[version='>=2.6.0'] -> six[version='>=1.10.0|>=1.15.0']
pandas==1.3.5 -> python-dateutil[version='>=2.7.3'] -> six[version='>=1.5']
pip -> html5lib -> six[version='>=1.9']
rdkit -> six

Package ca-certificates conflicts for:
pyfiglet==0.8.post1 -> python -> ca-certificates
python=3.8 -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1n,<1.1.2a'] -> ca-certificates
rdkit -> python=2.7 -> ca-certificates
pip -> python -> ca-certificates

Package typing_extensions conflicts for:
click==8.1.3 -> importlib-metadata -> typing_extensions[version='>=3.6.4']
tensorflow==2.6.0 -> tensorflow-base==2.6.0=gpu_py38hb3da07e_0 -> typing_extensions[version='>=3.7.4']

Package numpy conflicts for:
pandas==1.3.5 -> bottleneck[version='>=1.2.1'] -> numpy[version='1.11.*|1.12.*|1.13.*|>=1.11|>=1.11.3,<2.0a0|>=1.14.6,<2.0a0|>=1.16.5,<2.0a0|>=1.16.6,<2.0a0|>=1.21.3,<2.0a0|>=1.21.5,<2.0a0|>=1.21.6,<2.0a0|>=1.14.5,<2.0a0|>=1.9|>=1.8|>=1.21.2,<2.0a0|>=1.19.4,<2.0a0|>=1.16.4,<2.0a0|>=1.16.3,<2.0a0']
rdkit -> numpy[version='>=1.11|>=1.11.3,<2.0a0|>=1.14.6,<2.0a0|>=1.16.5,<2.0a0|>=1.16.6,<2.0a0|>=1.17.5,<2.0a0|>=1.18.5,<2.0a0|>=1.19.5,<2.0a0|>=1.21.6,<2.0a0|>=1.19.4,<2.0a0|>=1.19.2,<2.0a0']
tensorflow==2.6.0 -> tensorboard[version='>=2.6.0'] -> numpy[version='>=1.12.0|>=1.20|>=1.16.1']
rdkit -> boost[version='>=1.74.0,<1.74.1.0a0'] -> numpy[version='1.10.*|1.11.*|1.12.*|1.13.*|>=1.11.*|>=1.12.1,<2.0a0|>=1.15.4,<2.0a0|>=1.17|>=1.21.4,<2.0a0|>=1.21.5,<2.0a0|>=1.21.2,<2.0a0|>=1.9.*|>=1.9|>=1.8|>=1.7|>=1.20.3,<2.0a0|>=1.20.2,<2.0a0|>=1.13.3,<2.0a0|>=1.11.3,<1.12.0a0']
numpy==1.19.5
pandas==1.3.5 -> numpy[version='>=1.18.5,<2.0a0|>=1.19.5,<2.0a0|>=1.21.4,<2.0a0|>=1.19.2,<2.0a0']
biopython==1.79 -> numpy

Package jpeg conflicts for:
rdkit -> pillow -> jpeg[version='8.*|9.*|>=9c,<10a|>=9d,<10a|>=9e,<10a|>=9b,<10a']
tensorflow==2.6.0 -> tensorflow-base==2.6.0=gpu_py38hb3da07e_0 -> jpeg[version='>=9b,<10a|>=9d,<10a']

Package pypy3.7 conflicts for:
tensorflow==2.6.0 -> python=3.7 -> pypy3.7[version='7.3.5.*|7.3.7.*']
pandas==1.3.5 -> numpy[version='>=1.19.5,<2.0a0'] -> pypy3.7[version='7.3.*|7.3.5.*|7.3.7.*|>=7.3.5']
numpy==1.19.5 -> pypy3.7[version='>=7.3.5|>=7.3.7']
biopython==1.79 -> numpy -> pypy3.7[version='7.3.5.*|7.3.7.*|>=7.3.5|>=7.3.7']
click==8.1.3 -> importlib-metadata -> pypy3.7[version='7.3.5.*|7.3.7.*|>=7.3.5|>=7.3.7']
pandas==1.3.5 -> pypy3.7[version='>=7.3.7']
pyfiglet==0.8.post1 -> python -> pypy3.7[version='7.3.5.*|7.3.7.*|>=7.3.7|>=7.3.5']
pip -> python[version='>=3.7'] -> pypy3.7[version='7.3.5.*|7.3.7.*|>=7.3.7|>=7.3.5']
rdkit -> matplotlib-base -> pypy3.7[version='7.3.5.*|7.3.7.*|>=7.3.5|>=7.3.7']
numpy==1.19.5 -> python[version='>=3.7,<3.8.0a0'] -> pypy3.7[version='7.3.*|7.3.5.*|7.3.7.*']

Package colorama conflicts for:
click==8.1.3 -> colorama
pip -> colorama
python=3.8 -> pip -> colorama

Package numpy-base conflicts for:
rdkit -> numpy[version='>=1.21.6,<2.0a0'] -> numpy-base[version='1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.14.3|1.14.3|1.14.3|1.14.4|1.14.4|1.14.4|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.15.0|1.15.0|1.15.0|1.15.0|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.3|1.15.3|1.15.3|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.2|1.16.2|1.16.2|1.16.3|1.16.3|1.16.3|1.16.4|1.16.4|1.16.5|1.16.5|1.16.5|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.17.0|1.17.0|1.18.1.*|1.18.5.*|1.19.1|1.19.1|1.19.1|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.2|1.20.2|1.20.2|1.20.3|1.20.3|1.20.3|1.21.2|1.21.2|1.21.2|1.21.2|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.22.3|1.17.4.*|1.17.3.*|1.17.2.*',build='py27h0bb1d87_7|py36h5c71026_7|py37h5c71026_8|py27h0bb1d87_8|py36h4a99626_9|py37h8128ebf_9|py35h8128ebf_9|py36h8128ebf_10|py37h8128ebf_10|py27h2753ae9_10|py27hb1d0314_12|py36hc3f5095_12|py36h555522e_1|py27h917549b_1|py35h5c71026_0|py36h5c71026_0|py27h0bb1d87_0|py27h0bb1d87_0|py36h5c71026_0|py37h5c71026_0|py27h0bb1d87_1|py37h5c71026_1|py27h0bb1d87_3|py37h5c71026_3|py36h8128ebf_4|py27h2753ae9_4|py35h8128ebf_4|py27hb1d0314_5|py36hc3f5095_5|py35h4a99626_0|py36h4a99626_0|py27hfef472a_0|py37h4a99626_0|py37h8128ebf_0|py37h8128ebf_0|py37h8128ebf_0|py36hc3f5095_0|py27hb1d0314_0|py37hc3f5095_0|py37hc3f5095_0|py27hb1d0314_0|py36hc3f5095_0|py37hc3f5095_1|py37hc3f5095_0|py36hc3f5095_0|py37hc3f5095_0|py36hc3f5095_0|py36hc3f5095_0|py36hc3f5095_0|py37hc3f5095_0|py36hc3f5095_0|py37hc3f5095_0|py36hc3f5095_0|py38hc3f5095_0|py39h2e04a8b_1|py39h5bb6eb2_3|py39h378b42e_4|py37h378b42e_4|py36hc3f5095_0|py38ha3acd2a_0|py36ha3acd2a_0|py38ha3acd2a_0|py36ha3acd2a_0|py39h5bb6eb2_1|py37h5bb6eb2_1|py39h0829f74_0|py37h0829f74_0|py310h0829f74_0|py37hc2deb75_0|py37hca35cd5_1|py38hca35cd5_1|py39hca35cd5_2|py310h206c741_2|py37hca35cd5_2|py39hca35cd5_3|py310h206c741_3|py39hca35cd5_0|py38hca35cd5_0|py310h206c741_0|py38hca35cd5_3|py37hca35cd5_3|py38hca35cd5_2|py310h206c741_1|py39hca35cd5_1|py38hc2deb75_0|py310hedd7904_0|py39hc2deb75_0|py38h0829f74_0|py39hc2deb75_0|py38hc2deb75_0|py37hc2deb75_0|py38hc2deb75_0|py39hc2deb75_0|py37hc2deb75_0|py38haf7ebc8_0|py39haf7ebc8_0|py37haf7ebc8_0|py38h5bb6eb2_1|py39hbd0edd7_0|py37ha3acd2a_0|py37ha3acd2a_0|py37hc3f5095_0|py38h378b42e_4|py38h5bb6eb2_3|py36h5bb6eb2_3|py37h5bb6eb2_3|py27hb1d0314_0|py37hc3f5095_0|py27hb1d0314_0|py27hb1d0314_0|py37hc3f5095_0|py27hb1d0314_0|py27hb1d0314_1|py36hc3f5095_1|py37hc3f5095_1|py27hb1d0314_0|py27hb1d0314_1|py36hc3f5095_1|py27h2753ae9_0|py36h8128ebf_0|py27h2753ae9_0|py37h8128ebf_0|py36h8128ebf_0|py27h2753ae9_1|py36h8128ebf_0|py27h2753ae9_0|py35h8128ebf_0|py36h8128ebf_0|py27h2753ae9_0|py35h8128ebf_0|py37hc3f5095_5|py38hc3f5095_4|py37h8128ebf_4|py35h4a99626_4|py36h5c71026_4|py37h5c71026_4|py27h0bb1d87_4|py36h5c71026_3|py27h0bb1d87_2|py37h5c71026_2|py36h5c71026_2|py36h5c71026_1|py35h5c71026_0|py35h555522e_1|py38hc3f5095_12|py37hc3f5095_12|py27hb1d0314_11|py36h2a9b21d_11|py37h2a9b21d_11|py37h8128ebf_11|py36h8128ebf_11|py35h8128ebf_10|py27h2753ae9_9|py36h8128ebf_9|py27hfef472a_9|py37h4a99626_9|py35h4a99626_9|py35h4a99626_8|py36h5c71026_8|py37h5c71026_7']
biopython==1.79 -> numpy -> numpy-base[version='1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.14.3|1.14.3|1.14.3|1.14.4|1.14.4|1.14.4|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.15.0|1.15.0|1.15.0|1.15.0|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.3|1.15.3|1.15.3|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.2|1.16.2|1.16.2|1.16.3|1.16.3|1.16.3|1.16.4|1.16.4|1.16.5|1.16.5|1.16.5|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.17.0|1.22.3|1.22.3|1.22.3|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.2|1.21.2|1.21.2|1.21.2|1.20.3|1.20.3|1.20.3|1.20.2|1.20.2|1.20.2|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.1|1.19.1|1.19.1|1.18.5.*|1.18.1.*|1.17.4.*|1.17.3.*|1.17.2.*|1.9.3|1.9.3|1.9.3|1.9.3|1.9.3|1.9.3|1.9.3|>=1.9.3,<2.0a0',build='py36h5c71026_6|py27h0bb1d87_6|py27h0bb1d87_7|py36h5c71026_7|py37h5c71026_7|py27h0bb1d87_7|py37h5c71026_7|py37h5c71026_8|py27h0bb1d87_8|py37h4a99626_9|py36h8128ebf_10|py27h2753ae9_10|py27hb1d0314_12|py36hc3f5095_12|py27h917549b_1|py36h5c71026_0|py27h0bb1d87_0|py35h5c71026_0|py36h5c71026_0|py27h0bb1d87_1|py37h5c71026_1|py37h5c71026_2|py27h0bb1d87_3|py37h5c71026_3|py36h5c71026_4|py36h8128ebf_4|py37h8128ebf_4|py27h2753ae9_4|py35h8128ebf_4|py36hc3f5095_5|py36h4a99626_0|py27hfef472a_0|py37h4a99626_0|py27h2753ae9_0|py37h8128ebf_0|py37h8128ebf_0|py36hc3f5095_0|py27hb1d0314_0|py37hc3f5095_0|py36hc3f5095_0|py37hc3f5095_1|py36hc3f5095_0|py37hc3f5095_0|py36hc3f5095_0|py36hc3f5095_0|py36hc3f5095_0|py37hc3f5095_0|py36hc3f5095_0|py37hc3f5095_0|py36hc3f5095_0|py38hc3f5095_0|py36h5bb6eb2_3|py39h378b42e_4|py37h378b42e_4|py38ha3acd2a_0|py36ha3acd2a_0|py38ha3acd2a_0|py37ha3acd2a_0|py36ha3acd2a_0|py39h5bb6eb2_1|py37h5bb6eb2_1|py38h5bb6eb2_1|py37hc2deb75_0|py39hc2deb75_0|py39h0829f74_0|py37h0829f74_0|py39hc2deb75_0|py37hca35cd5_1|py38hca35cd5_1|py39hca35cd5_1|py310h206c741_1|py310h206c741_2|py37hca35cd5_2|py38hca35cd5_3|py310h206c741_3|py36hc3f5095_0|py37hc3f5095_0|py38hca35cd5_0|py310h206c741_0|py39hca35cd5_0|py37hca35cd5_3|py39hca35cd5_3|py39hca35cd5_2|py38hca35cd5_2|py37hc2deb75_0|py38hc2deb75_0|py310hedd7904_0|py310h0829f74_0|py38h0829f74_0|py38hc2deb75_0|py37hc2deb75_0|py38hc2deb75_0|py39hc2deb75_0|py38haf7ebc8_0|py39haf7ebc8_0|py37haf7ebc8_0|py39hbd0edd7_0|py37ha3acd2a_0|py38h378b42e_4|py38h5bb6eb2_3|py39h5bb6eb2_3|py37h5bb6eb2_3|py39h2e04a8b_1|py27hb1d0314_0|py37hc3f5095_0|py27hb1d0314_0|py27hb1d0314_0|py37hc3f5095_0|py27hb1d0314_0|py27hb1d0314_1|py36hc3f5095_1|py37hc3f5095_1|py37hc3f5095_0|py27hb1d0314_0|py27hb1d0314_1|py36hc3f5095_1|py27hb1d0314_0|py37hc3f5095_0|py27h2753ae9_0|py36h8128ebf_0|py27h2753ae9_0|py36h8128ebf_0|py27h2753ae9_1|py37h8128ebf_0|py36h8128ebf_0|py35h8128ebf_0|py36h8128ebf_0|py27h2753ae9_0|py35h8128ebf_0|py37h8128ebf_0|py35h4a99626_0|py27hb1d0314_5|py37hc3f5095_5|py38hc3f5095_4|py35h4a99626_4|py37h5c71026_4|py27h0bb1d87_4|py36h5c71026_3|py27h0bb1d87_2|py36h5c71026_2|py36h5c71026_1|py37h5c71026_0|py27h0bb1d87_0|py35h5c71026_0|py36h555522e_1|py35h555522e_1|py38hc3f5095_12|py37hc3f5095_12|py27hb1d0314_11|py36h2a9b21d_11|py37h2a9b21d_11|py37h8128ebf_11|py36h8128ebf_11|py37h8128ebf_10|py35h8128ebf_10|py27h2753ae9_9|py35h8128ebf_9|py36h8128ebf_9|py37h8128ebf_9|py27hfef472a_9|py36h4a99626_9|py35h4a99626_9|py35h4a99626_8|py36h5c71026_8|py36h5c71026_7|py35h5c71026_7|py37h5c71026_6']
pandas==1.3.5 -> numpy[version='>=1.19.5,<2.0a0'] -> numpy-base[version='1.18.5.*|1.19.1|1.19.1|1.19.1|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.2|1.20.2|1.20.2|1.20.3|1.20.3|1.20.3|1.21.2|1.21.2|1.21.2|1.21.2|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.22.3|>=1.17.3,<2.0a0',build='py38ha3acd2a_0|py36ha3acd2a_0|py38ha3acd2a_0|py36ha3acd2a_0|py39h5bb6eb2_1|py37h5bb6eb2_1|py39h0829f74_0|py37h0829f74_0|py310h0829f74_0|py37hc2deb75_0|py37hca35cd5_1|py38hca35cd5_1|py39hca35cd5_2|py310h206c741_2|py37hca35cd5_2|py39hca35cd5_3|py310h206c741_3|py39hca35cd5_0|py38hca35cd5_0|py310h206c741_0|py38hca35cd5_3|py37hca35cd5_3|py38hca35cd5_2|py310h206c741_1|py39hca35cd5_1|py38hc2deb75_0|py310hedd7904_0|py39hc2deb75_0|py38h0829f74_0|py39hc2deb75_0|py38hc2deb75_0|py37hc2deb75_0|py38hc2deb75_0|py39hc2deb75_0|py37hc2deb75_0|py38haf7ebc8_0|py39haf7ebc8_0|py37haf7ebc8_0|py38h5bb6eb2_1|py39hbd0edd7_0|py37ha3acd2a_0|py37ha3acd2a_0']
```

Comment: Interpreting Conda's conflict reporting [is notoriously difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62288835/how-to-interpret-conda-package-conflicts). Instead, could you add to the question the actual requirements section of the `meta.yaml` for the package you are attempting to build? Otherwise, `conda-build` doesn't do anything different than Conda - it tries to create (potentially) three environments: 1) build environment; 2) host environment; 3) run/test environment.

Comment: Also, worth noting that this seems to be on **win-64** platform, but Bioconda only support **linux-64** and **osx-64**. Though, it's not clear if the package has any real dependency on Bioconda.