# Error: Specifications incompatible with each other

Tags: conda, glibc

I have been working in a Python3.8 virtual environment which I created.
I am trying to install [a package](https://github.com/GINsim/GINsim-python) with conda and I am getting the following error:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versionsThe following specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:

  - feature:/linux-64::__glibc==2.31=0
  - python=3.8.10 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.5.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']

Your installed version is: 2.31
```

I have seen that similar errors can be caused by using different channels, but I have not installed anything else in this virtual environment. How I can interpret and solve the above?

This is what is currently installed in my environment

```
$ pip list
Package    Version
---------- ---------
certifi    2022.6.15
pip        22.1.2
setuptools 61.2.0
wheel      0.37.1
```

Edit: Added installed packages

Comment: Can you add a list of what is currently installed in your env?

Comment: @FlyingTeller I just updated my post to include this

Comment: What happens when you create the environemnt with all specifications from the start: `conda env create -n <some name> -c colomoto ginsim-python python=3.8 pip`?

Comment: @FlyingTeller I get an error: conda-env: error: unrecognized arguments: -c ginsim-python python=3.8 pip

Comment: My bad, should have been `conda create -n <some name> -c colomoto ginsim-python python=3.8 pip`, no `env`. Probably need to add `conda-forge` as well: `conda create -n ginsim -c conda-forge -c colomoto ginsim-python python=3.8 pip`

Comment: @FlyingTeller That worked with no issues. Thank you! Could you explain why this error does not appear when you have all the specifications from the start?

Comment: Could be that the `-c conda-forge` was the actual trick here. However I have noticed that sometimes the `conda` solver just get's kind of stuck when trying to bring existing packages and new dependencies together. Then it is always a good idea to try and start with a fresh env, specifying all required packages from the start

Comment: FYI, when using Conda environment, please show `conda list` not `pip list`. Also, [Conda is bad at conflict reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62288835/how-to-interpret-conda-package-conflicts) - it is obvious GLIBC==2.31 satisfies >=2.17.