# Python dependency conflicts

Tags: python, conda, conflict

I am trying to understand the problem with my Environment (I am using conda).
I am trying to install matplotlib package, I tried other version of matplot lib, but it always showing me error in this pattern:

```
(myEnv) D:\myProject>conda install matplotlib=3.5
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: /
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed                                                                                                                                                                                                          |

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with a past
explicit spec that is not an explicit spec in this operation (pip):

  - matplotlib=3.5 -> matplotlib-base[version='>=3.5.3,<3.5.4.0a0'] -> numpy[version='>=1.19.2,<2.0a0|>=1.21.5,<2.0a0|>=1.21.2,<2.0a0']
  - matplotlib=3.5 -> matplotlib-base[version='>=3.5.3,<3.5.4.0a0'] -> pillow[version='>=6.2.0']
  - matplotlib=3.5 -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> pip

The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

Package libxml2 conflicts for:
fontconfig -> libxml2[version='>=2.10.3,<2.11.0a0|>=2.9.14,<2.10.0a0']
cairo -> fontconfig[version='>=2.14.1,<3.0a0'] -> libxml2[version='>=2.10.3,<2.11.0a0|>=2.9.14,<2.10.0a0']

Package ca-certificates conflicts for:
mkl-service -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0'] -> ca-certificates
setuptools -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0'] -> ca-certificates
docutils -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0'] -> ca-certificates
openssl -> ca-certificates
ca-certificates
numpy-base -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0'] -> ca-certificates
pygments -> python -> ca-certificates
pip -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0'] -> ca-certificates
mkl_fft -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0'] -> ca-certificates
wheel -> python -> ca-certificates
pillow -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0'] -> ca-certificates
six -> python -> ca-certificates
python=3.10 -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1t,<1.1.2a'] -> ca-certificates

Package libtiff conflicts for:
libtiff
sdl2_image -> libtiff[version='>=4.5.0,<4.6.0a0']
kivy -> pillow -> libtiff[version='>=4.0.10,<5.0a0|>=4.2.0,<5.0a0|>=4.1.0,<5.0a0|>=4.0.9,<5.0a0|>=4.0.8,<5.0a0|>=4.5.0,<4.6.0a0']
pillow -> libtiff[version='>=4.0.10,<5.0a0|>=4.2.0,<5.0a0|>=4.1.0,<5.0a0|>=4.0.9,<5.0a0|>=4.0.8,<5.0a0']
libwebp -> libtiff[version='>=4.1.0,<5.0a0']

Package icu conflicts for:
icu
harfbuzz -> icu[version='>=58.2,<59.0a0|>=72.1,<73.0a0']
cairo -> icu[version='>=58.2,<59.0a0|>=72.1,<73.0a0']

Package libwebp-base conflicts for:
libwebp-base
kivy -> sdl2_image[version='>=2.6.2,<3.0a0'] -> libwebp-base[version='>=1.2.4,<2.0a0']
sdl2_image -> libwebp-base[version='>=1.2.4,<2.0a0']
libwebp -> libwebp-base=1.2.4
pillow -> libwebp[version='>=1.2.0,<1.3.0a0'] -> libwebp-base=1.2.4

Package ucrt conflicts for:
zstd -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0'] -> ucrt[version='>=10.0.20348.0']
freetype -> libpng[version='>=1.6.37,<1.7.0a0'] -> ucrt[version='>=10.0.20348.0']
python=3.10 -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0'] -> ucrt[version='>=10.0.20348.0']
numpy-base -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.27.29016,<15.0a0'] -> ucrt[version='>=10.0.20348.0']
intel-openmp -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0'] -> ucrt[version='>=10.0.20348.0']
libdeflate -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0'] -> ucrt[version='>=10.0.20348.0']
mpg123 -> ucrt[version='>=10.0.20348.0']
libwebp-base -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0'] -> ucrt[version='>=10.0.20348.0']
aom -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.29.30139'] -> ucrt[version='>=10.0.20348.0']
harfbuzz -> ucrt[version='>=10.0.20348.0']
libavif -> ucrt[version='>=10.0.20348.0']
sqlite -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0'] -> ucrt[version='>=10.0.20348.0']
vc -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.27.29016'] -> ucrt[version='>=10.0.20348.0']
libglib -> ucrt[version='>=10.0.20348.0']
mkl-service -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0'] -> ucrt[version='>=10.0.20348.0']
kivy -> ucrt[version='>=10.0.20348.0']
libpng -> ucrt[version='>=10.0.20348.0']
icu -> ucrt[version='>=10.0.20348.0']
tbb -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0'] -> ucrt[version='>=10.0.20348.0']
libffi -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0'] -> ucrt[version='>=10.0.20348.0']
tk -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0'] -> ucrt[version='>=10.0.20348.0']
sdl2 -> ucrt[version='>=10.0.20348.0']
glew -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0'] -> ucrt[version='>=10.0.20348.0']
openssl -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0'] -> ucrt[version='>=10.0.20348.0']
libmad -> ucrt[version='>=10.0.20348.0']
sdl2_image -> ucrt[version='>=10.0.20348.0']
lz4-c -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0'] -> ucrt[version='>=10.0.20348.0']
vs2015_runtime -> ucrt[version='>=10.0.20348.0']
zlib -> ucrt[version='>=10.0.20348.0']
libvorbis -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0'] -> ucrt[version='>=10.0.20348.0']
expat -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0'] -> ucrt[version='>=10.0.20348.0']
pcre2 -> ucrt[version='>=10.0.20348.0']
cairo -> ucrt[version='>=10.0.20348.0']
numpy==1.21.2 -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0'] -> ucrt[version='>=10.0.20348.0']
pillow -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0'] -> ucrt[version='>=10.0.20348.0']
sdl2_mixer -> ucrt[version='>=10.0.20348.0']
ucrt
libogg -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0'] -> ucrt[version='>=10.0.20348.0']
pixman -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0'] -> ucrt[version='>=10.0.20348.0']
graphite2 -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0'] -> ucrt[version='>=10.0.20348.0']
libzlib -> ucrt[version='>=10.0.20348.0']
libflac -> ucrt[version='>=10.0.20348.0']
lerc -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0'] -> ucrt[version='>=10.0.20348.0']
libwebp -> libpng[version='>=1.6.37,<1.7.0a0'] -> ucrt[version='>=10.0.20348.0']
fontconfig -> ucrt[version='>=10.0.20348.0']
jpeg -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0'] -> ucrt[version='>=10.0.20348.0']
mkl_fft -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0'] -> ucrt[version='>=10.0.20348.0']
libtiff -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0'] -> ucrt[version='>=10.0.20348.0']
mkl_random -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0'] -> ucrt[version='>=10.0.20348.0']
dav1d -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27033'] -> ucrt[version='>=10.0.20348.0']
libiconv -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0'] -> ucrt[version='>=10.0.20348.0']
mkl -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0'] -> ucrt[version='>=10.0.20348.0']
xz -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0'] -> ucrt[version='>=10.0.20348.0']

Package numpy conflicts for:
numpy==1.21.2
numpy-base -> mkl-service[version='>=2,<3.0a0'] -> numpy[version='>=1.11.3,<2.0a0']
mkl-service -> numpy[version='>=1.11.3,<2.0a0']
mkl_fft -> numpy[version='>=1.11.3,<2.0a0|>=1.14.6,<2.0a0|>=1.16,<2.0a0|>=1.21,<2.0a0|>=1.23,<2.0a0|>=1.22,<2.0a0|>=1.16.6,<2.0a0']
mkl_random -> numpy[version='>=1.11.3,<2.0a0|>=1.14,<2.0a0|>=1.16,<2.0a0|>=1.21,<2.0a0|>=1.23,<2.0a0|>=1.22,<2.0a0|>=1.14.6,<2.0a0']

Package vs2015_runtime conflicts for:
aom -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.29.30139']
libffi -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15.0a0'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.15.26706|>=14.27.29016|>=14.16.27012']
aom -> vc[version='>=14.2,<15'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.27.29016']
openssl -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0']
vs2015_runtime
libwebp-base -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0']
libtiff -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15.0a0'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.0.25123,<15.0a0|>=14.0.25420|>=14.15.26706|>=14.27.29016|>=14.16.27012|>=14.29.30139']
mkl_random -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0']
lz4-c -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0']
intel-openmp -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15.0a0'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.15.26706|>=14.27.29016|>=14.16.27012']
lz4-c -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15.0a0'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.0.25123,<15.0a0|>=14.0.25420|>=14.15.26706|>=14.27.29016|>=14.16.27012']
expat -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15.0a0'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.0.25123,<15.0a0|>=14.0.25420|>=14.15.26706|>=14.27.29016|>=14.16.27012']
matplotlib=3.5 -> matplotlib-base[version='>=3.5.3,<3.5.4.0a0'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0']
numpy-base -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0|>=14.27.29016,<15.0a0']
cairo -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0|>=14.29.30139']
zlib -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0|>=14.29.30139']
dav1d -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.15.26706|>=14.27.29016|>=14.16.27012']
mpg123 -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.29.30139']
pcre2 -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0|>=14.29.30139']
zstd -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0']
freetype -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0']
cairo -> pixman[version='>=0.40.0,<1.0a0'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.0.25123,<15.0a0|>=14.0.25420|>=14.15.26706|>=14.16.27012|>=14.27.29016']
sdl2_mixer -> libogg[version='>=1.3.4,<1.4.0a0'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012|>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0|>=14.27.29016']
libogg -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15.0a0'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.15.26706|>=14.27.29016']
sdl2_image -> jpeg[version='>=9e,<10a'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0|>=14.27.29016']
pixman -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012|>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0']
pillow -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15.0a0'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.0.25123,<15.0a0|>=14.0.25420|>=14.15.26706|>=14.27.29016|>=14.16.27012|>=14.29.30139']
pixman -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15.0a0'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.0.25123,<15.0a0|>=14.0.25420|>=14.15.26706|>=14.27.29016']
mkl_fft -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0']
docutils -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0']
libglib -> libffi[version='>=3.4,<4.0a0'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0|>=14.16.27033|>=14.27.29016']
pcre2 -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15.0a0'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.15.26706|>=14.27.29016|>=14.16.27012']
mkl_random -> numpy[version='>=1.21,<2.0a0'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.0.25123,<15.0a0|>=14.0.25420|>=14.15.26706|>=14.27.29016|>=14.27.29016,<15.0a0|>=14.16.27012']
zstd -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15.0a0'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.0.25123,<15.0a0|>=14.0.25420|>=14.15.26706|>=14.27.29016|>=14.16.27012|>=14.29.30139']
libzlib -> vc[version='>=14.2,<15'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.27.29016']
libwebp-base -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15.0a0'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.15.26706|>=14.27.29016|>=14.16.27012']
lerc -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15.0a0'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.15.26706|>=14.27.29016|>=14.16.27012']
wheel -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0']
lerc -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0']
setuptools -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0']
libmad -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.29.30139']
jpeg -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15.0a0'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.0.25123,<15.0a0|>=14.0.25420|>=14.15.26706|>=14.27.29016|>=14.16.27012']
libdeflate -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0']
libiconv -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15.0a0'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.0.25123,<15.0a0|>=14.0.25420|>=14.15.26706|>=14.27.29016|>=14.16.27012']
libflac -> libogg=1.3 -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012|>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0|>=14.27.29016']
libogg -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012|>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0']
python=3.10 -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15.0a0'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.15.26706|>=14.27.29016|>=14.16.27012|>=14.29.30139']
intel-openmp -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0']
icu -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15.0a0'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.0.25123,<15.0a0|>=14.0.25420|>=14.15.26706|>=14.27.29016|>=14.16.27012']
harfbuzz -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0|>=14.27.29016,<15.0a0|>=14.29.30139']
libtiff -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0']
xz -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15.0a0'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.0.25123,<15.0a0|>=14.0.25420|>=14.15.26706|>=14.27.29016|>=14.16.27012']
sdl2 -> vc[version='>=14.2,<15'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.27.29016']
libmad -> vc[version='>=14.2,<15'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.27.29016']
glew -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15.0a0'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.15.26706|>=14.27.29016']
numpy==1.21.2 -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0']
numpy-base -> vc[version='>=14.2,<15.0a0'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.0.25123,<15.0a0|>=14.0.25420|>=14.15.26706|>=14.27.29016|>=14.16.27012']
mkl -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0']
sqlite -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15.0a0'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.0.25123,<15.0a0|>=14.0.25420|>=14.15.26706|>=14.27.29016|>=14.16.27012|>=14.29.30139']
pillow -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0']
expat -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0']
libglib -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.29.30139']
libzlib -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.29.30139']
libwebp -> libpng[version='>=1.6.37,<1.7.0a0'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.0.25123,<15.0a0|>=14.0.25420|>=14.15.26706|>=14.27.29016|>=14.29.30139|>=14.16.27012']
mpg123 -> vc[version='>=14.2,<15'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.27.29016']
python=3.10 -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0']
kivy -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.29.30139']
graphite2 -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15.0a0'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.0.25123,<15.0a0|>=14.0.25420|>=14.15.26706|>=14.27.29016|>=14.16.27012']
six -> python -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0']
libwebp -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0']
libavif -> dav1d[version='>=1.0.0,<1.0.1.0a0'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27033|>=14.27.29016']
xz -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0']
gettext -> libiconv[version='>=1.17,<2.0a0'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27033']
libvorbis -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15.0a0'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.15.26706|>=14.27.29016']
glew -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012|>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0']
icu -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0|>=14.29.30139']
sdl2_image -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.29.30139']
tbb -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15.0a0'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.0.25123,<15.0a0|>=14.0.25420|>=14.15.26706|>=14.27.29016|>=14.16.27012']
libpng -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15.0a0'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.0.25123,<15.0a0|>=14.0.25420|>=14.15.26706|>=14.27.29016|>=14.16.27012']
tbb -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0']
tk -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15.0a0'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.0.25123,<15.0a0|>=14.0.25420|>=14.15.26706|>=14.27.29016|>=14.16.27012']
jpeg -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0']
mkl -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15.0a0'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.15.26706|>=14.27.29016|>=14.16.27012']
sdl2 -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.29.30139']
tk -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0']
dav1d -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27033']
graphite2 -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0']
fontconfig -> libiconv[version='>=1.16,<2.0a0'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.15.26706|>=14.16.27033|>=14.27.29016|>=14.16.27012']
zlib -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15.0a0'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.0.25123,<15.0a0|>=14.0.25420|>=14.15.26706|>=14.27.29016|>=14.16.27012']
pygments -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0']
libiconv -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0|>=14.16.27033']
numpy==1.21.2 -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15.0a0'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.15.26706|>=14.27.29016|>=14.16.27012']
openssl -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15.0a0'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.0.25123,<15.0a0|>=14.0.25420|>=14.15.26706|>=14.27.29016|>=14.16.27012']
libffi -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0']
mkl_fft -> numpy[version='>=1.21,<2.0a0'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.0.25123,<15.0a0|>=14.0.25420|>=14.15.26706|>=14.27.29016|>=14.27.29016,<15.0a0|>=14.16.27012']
sdl2_mixer -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.29.30139']
libdeflate -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15.0a0'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.15.26706|>=14.27.29016|>=14.16.27012']
libavif -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.29.30139']
python_abi -> python=3.10 -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0']
vc -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.0.25123,<15.0a0|>=14.0.25420|>=14.15.26706|>=14.27.29016|>=14.16.27012']
libpng -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0|>=14.29.30139']
bzip2 -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15.0a0'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.0.25123,<15.0a0|>=14.0.25420|>=14.15.26706|>=14.27.29016|>=14.16.27012']
freetype -> libpng[version='>=1.6.37,<1.7.0a0'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.0.25123,<15.0a0|>=14.0.25420|>=14.15.26706|>=14.27.29016|>=14.29.30139|>=14.16.27012']
kivy -> glew[version='>=2.1.0,<2.2.0a0'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012|>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0|>=14.27.29016']
mkl-service -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15.0a0'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.0.25123,<15.0a0|>=14.0.25420|>=14.15.26706|>=14.27.29016|>=14.16.27012|>=14.27.29016,<15.0a0']
sqlite -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0']
mkl-service -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0']
pip -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0']
harfbuzz -> vc[version='>=14.2,<15.0a0'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.15.26706|>=14.27.29016|>=14.16.27012']
fontconfig -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0|>=14.29.30139']
libflac -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.29.30139']
libvorbis -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012|>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0']

Package zlib conflicts for:
harfbuzz -> cairo[version='>=1.16.0,<2.0a0'] -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.12,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.13,<1.3.0a0']
setuptools -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.12,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.13,<1.3.0a0']
python=3.10 -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.12,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.13,<1.3.0a0']
wheel -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.12,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.13,<1.3.0a0']
pillow -> libtiff[version='>=4.2.0,<5.0a0'] -> zlib[version='>=1.2.12,<1.3.0a0']
cairo -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.12,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.13,<1.3.0a0']
sdl2_image -> libpng[version='>=1.6.39,<1.7.0a0'] -> zlib[version='>=1.2.13,<1.3.0a0']
mkl_fft -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.12,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.13,<1.3.0a0']
zlib
python_abi -> python=3.10 -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.12,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.13,<1.3.0a0']
pillow -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.13,<1.3.0a0']
numpy==1.21.2 -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.12,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.13,<1.3.0a0']
six -> python -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.12,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.13,<1.3.0a0']
fontconfig -> freetype[version='>=2.10.4,<3.0a0'] -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.12,<1.3.0a0']
libtiff -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.12,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.13,<1.3.0a0']
numpy-base -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.12,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.13,<1.3.0a0']
mkl-service -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.12,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.13,<1.3.0a0']
matplotlib=3.5 -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.12,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.13,<1.3.0a0']
pcre2 -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.13,<1.3.0a0']
pygments -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.12,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.13,<1.3.0a0']
zstd -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.12,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.13,<1.3.0a0']
pip -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.12,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.13,<1.3.0a0']
fontconfig -> zlib[version='>=1.2.13,<1.3.0a0']
docutils -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.12,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.13,<1.3.0a0']
kivy -> pillow -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.13,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.12,<1.3.0a0']
sqlite -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']
libpng -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.13,<1.3.0a0']
freetype -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.13,<1.3.0a0']
libwebp -> libpng[version='>=1.6.37,<1.7.0a0'] -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.13,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.12,<1.3.0a0']
mkl_random -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.12,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.13,<1.3.0a0']

Package vc conflicts for:
pillow -> vc[version='14.*|9.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0']
libwebp -> vc[version='14.*|9.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0']
bzip2 -> vc[version='14.*|9.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0']
python_abi -> python=3.10 -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15.0a0']
kivy -> glew[version='>=2.1.0,<2.2.0a0'] -> vc[version='14.*|9.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0']
mkl_fft -> numpy[version='>=1.21,<2.0a0'] -> vc[version='>=14.2,<15.0a0']
libflac -> libogg=1.3 -> vc[version='9.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0']
harfbuzz -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15.0a0|>=14.2,<15.0a0|>=14.2,<15']
pillow -> zlib[version='>=1.2.13,<1.3.0a0'] -> vc[version='>=14.2,<15']
libtiff -> vc[version='14.*|9.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0']
openssl -> vc[version='14.*|9.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0']
wheel -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> vc[version='14.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0|9.*']
fontconfig -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15.0a0|>=14.2,<15']
matplotlib=3.5 -> matplotlib-base[version='>=3.5.3,<3.5.4.0a0'] -> vc[version='14.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0|9.*']
pcre2 -> bzip2[version='>=1.0.8,<2.0a0'] -> vc[version='14.*|9.*']
zstd -> zlib[version='>=1.2.13,<1.3.0a0'] -> vc[version='>=14.2,<15']
numpy-base -> vc[version='14.*|9.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0|>=14.2,<15.0a0']
libvorbis -> vc[version='9.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0']
sqlite -> vc[version='14.*|9.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0']
mkl-service -> vc[version='14.*|9.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0']
libmad -> vc[version='>=14.2,<15']
libwebp-base -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15.0a0']
dav1d -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15']
libpng -> vc[version='14.*|9.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0|>=14.2,<15']
setuptools -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> vc[version='14.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0|9.*']
pcre2 -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15.0a0|>=14.2,<15']
sdl2_image -> vc[version='>=14.2,<15']
libffi -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15.0a0']
libzlib -> vc[version='>=14.2,<15']
libavif -> vc[version='>=14.2,<15']
mkl-service -> numpy[version='>=1.11.3,<2.0a0'] -> vc[version='>=14.2,<15.0a0']
tbb -> vc[version='14.*|9.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0']
libglib -> vc[version='>=14.2,<15']
six -> python -> vc[version='14.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0|9.*']
kivy -> vc[version='>=14.2,<15']
sqlite -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0'] -> vc[version='>=14.2,<15']
pixman -> vc[version='14.*|9.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0']
harfbuzz -> icu[version='>=58.2,<59.0a0'] -> vc[version='14.*|9.*']
tk -> vc[version='14.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0|9.*']
freetype -> vc[version='14.*|9.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0']
expat -> vc[version='14.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0|9.*']
numpy==1.21.2 -> mkl-service[version='>=2.3.0,<3.0a0'] -> vc[version='14.*|9.*']
libiconv -> vc[version='14.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0|9.*|>=14.1,<15']
python=3.10 -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15.0a0']
glew -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15.0a0']
sdl2 -> vc[version='>=14.2,<15']
zstd -> vc[version='14.*|9.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0']
graphite2 -> vc[version='14.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0']
fontconfig -> libiconv[version='>=1.16,<2.0a0'] -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15']
zlib -> vc[version='14.*|9.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0|>=14.2,<15']
mkl_fft -> vc[version='14.*|9.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0']
sdl2_mixer -> libogg[version='>=1.3.4,<1.4.0a0'] -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15.0a0']
python=3.10 -> bzip2[version='>=1.0.8,<2.0a0'] -> vc[version='14.*|9.*|>=14.2,<15']
icu -> vc[version='14.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0|9.*|>=14.2,<15']
libglib -> libffi[version='>=3.4,<4.0a0'] -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15|>=14.1,<15.0a0']
sdl2_mixer -> vc[version='>=14.2,<15']
lz4-c -> vc[version='14.*|9.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0']
vc
mpg123 -> vc[version='>=14.2,<15']
docutils -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> vc[version='14.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0|9.*']
libavif -> dav1d[version='>=1.0.0,<1.0.1.0a0'] -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15']
jpeg -> vc[version='14.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0|9.*']
numpy==1.21.2 -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15.0a0']
mkl -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15.0a0']
libflac -> vc[version='>=14.2,<15']
pygments -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> vc[version='14.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0|9.*']
aom -> vc[version='>=14.2,<15']
intel-openmp -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15.0a0']
mkl_random -> mkl-service[version='>=2.3.0,<3.0a0'] -> vc[version='9.*|>=14.2,<15.0a0']
libogg -> vc[version='9.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0']
lerc -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15.0a0']
libwebp -> libpng[version='>=1.6.37,<1.7.0a0'] -> vc[version='>=14.2,<15']
cairo -> vc[version='14.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0|9.*|>=14.2,<15']
mkl_random -> vc[version='14.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0']
pip -> python[version='>=3.11,<3.12.0a0'] -> vc[version='14.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0|9.*']
gettext -> libiconv[version='>=1.17,<2.0a0'] -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15']
sdl2_image -> jpeg[version='>=9e,<10a'] -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15.0a0']
libtiff -> zlib[version='>=1.2.13,<1.3.0a0'] -> vc[version='>=14.2,<15']
libdeflate -> vc[version='>=14.1,<15.0a0']
xz -> vc[version='14.*|9.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0']
freetype -> libpng[version='>=1.6.37,<1.7.0a0'] -> vc[version='>=14.2,<15']

Package mkl conflicts for:
mkl-service -> mkl[version='>=2018.0.0,<2019.0a0|>=2018.0.3,<2019.0a0|>=2019.1,<2021.0a0|>=2019.3,<2021.0a0|>=2019.4,<2021.0a0|>=2021.2.0,<2022.0a0|>=2021.4.0,<2022.0a0|>=2023.1.0,<2024.0a0']
numpy-base -> mkl[version='>=2018.0.2,<2019.0a0|>=2018.0.3,<2019.0a0|>=2019.1,<2021.0a0|>=2019.3,<2021.0a0|>=2019.4,<2021.0a0|>=2021.2.0,<2022.0a0|>=2021.3.0,<2022.0a0|>=2021.4.0,<2022.0a0|>=2023.1.0,<2024.0a0|>=2019.4,<2020.0a0']
mkl-service -> numpy[version='>=1.11.3,<2.0a0'] -> mkl[version='>=2018.0.1,<2019.0a0|>=2018.0.2,<2019.0a0|>=2021.3.0,<2022.0a0|>=2019.4,<2020.0a0']
numpy==1.21.2 -> mkl[version='>=2021.3.0,<2022.0a0|>=2021.4.0,<2022.0a0']
mkl
mkl_fft -> mkl[version='>=2018.0.3,<2019.0a0|>=2019.1,<2021.0a0|>=2019.3,<2021.0a0|>=2019.4,<2021.0a0|>=2021.2.0,<2022.0a0|>=2021.3.0,<2022.0a0|>=2021.4.0,<2022.0a0|>=2023.1.0,<2024.0a0|>=2019.4,<2020.0a0']
mkl_random -> numpy[version='>=1.21,<2.0a0'] -> mkl[version='>=2018.0.0,<2019.0a0|>=2018.0.1,<2019.0a0|>=2018.0.2,<2019.0a0|>=2019.3,<2021.0a0|>=2021.3.0,<2022.0a0']
mkl_fft -> numpy-base[version='>=1.2.1,<2.0a0'] -> mkl[version='>=2018.0.0,<2019.0a0|>=2018.0.1,<2019.0a0|>=2018.0.2,<2019.0a0']
mkl_random -> mkl[version='>=2018.0.3,<2019.0a0|>=2019.1,<2021.0a0|>=2019.4,<2021.0a0|>=2020.1,<2021.0a0|>=2021.2.0,<2022.0a0|>=2021.4.0,<2022.0a0|>=2023.1.0,<2024.0a0|>=2019.4,<2020.0a0']
numpy==1.21.2 -> mkl-service[version='>=2.3.0,<3.0a0'] -> mkl[version='>=2018.0.3,<2019.0a0|>=2019.1,<2021.0a0|>=2019.3,<2021.0a0|>=2019.4,<2021.0a0|>=2021.2.0,<2022.0a0|>=2023.1.0,<2024.0a0|>=2019.4,<2020.0a0|>=2020.1,<2021.0a0']

Package olefile conflicts for:
pillow -> olefile
kivy -> pillow -> olefile
```

(it was too long, I delete ~70% of the conflicts)

about the first conflicts:

```
  - matplotlib=3.5 -> matplotlib-base[version='>=3.5.3,<3.5.4.0a0'] -> numpy[version='>=1.19.2,<2.0a0|>=1.21.5,<2.0a0|>=1.21.2,<2.0a0']
  - matplotlib=3.5 -> matplotlib-base[version='>=3.5.3,<3.5.4.0a0'] -> pillow[version='>=6.2.0']
  - matplotlib=3.5 -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> pip
```

my numpy version is: 1.21.2
my Pillow version is: 9.4.0
and my Python version is: 3.10
I dont understanding the issue here..

In addition, it seem I have plenty of internal conflicts, and its not making any sense, like the first paragraph of "Package ucrt conflicts for: ... "

How can I solve those conflicts?
And what I missed in my reading the conflicts-errors?

Comment: There is info on interpreting conflict reports here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62288835/570918. Otherwise, the thing that jumps out at me is you have a hard defined `numpy=1.21.2` in your explicit specifications. What happens if you loosen that up with: `conda install matplotlib=3.5 'numpy>=1.21.2'` (be sure to use the quotes!)

Comment: Hi merv, I look on this link, it was very helpful to understand the "AND" & "OR" segments.
But they not explain how to find the conflicts (Just it is difficult), and tring Mamba.
BTW, for soft defined I just need to add quotes for every package? like conda install "numpy"?

Comment: Quotes whenever you define a bound, like (`'numpy>=1.21.2'`), otherwise, shells will interpret the `>` as a redirect. On the conflicts, I've encountered cases where the Conda output never includes a proper conflict, so there isn't any methodological guidance to give. Mamba will actually identify at least one real conflict, but sometimes it reports irrelevant version numbers.