# How to extract text from online PDF using pdfminer in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, pdfminer

I want to extract text from online PDF using pdfminer using below code, it is showing no error but output is nothing

```
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from urllib import request
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from io import StringIO
from io import open

def readPDF(pdfFile):
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = StringIO()
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, laparams=laparams)
    PDFPage.get_pages(rsrcmgr, device, pdfFile)
    device.close()
    content = retstr.getvalue()
    retstr.close()
    return content

pdfFile = request.urlopen("https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/cancer/9/0/9_KJ00003588219/_pdf/-char/en")
outputString = readPDF(pdfFile)
print(outputString)
```

Answer (score 2):

Following code works in Python 3.7.4

```
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
import io
import urllib.request
import requests


def pdf_to_text(pdf_file):
    text_memory_file = io.StringIO()

    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, text_memory_file, laparams=LAParams())
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    # get first 3 pages of the pdf file
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(pdf_file, pagenos=(0, 1, 2)):
        interpreter.process_page(page)
    text = text_memory_file.getvalue()
    text_memory_file.close()
    return text

# # online pdf to text by urllib
# online_pdf_file=urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.dabeaz.com/python/UnderstandingGIL.pdf')
# pdf_memory_file=io.BytesIO()
# pdf_memory_file.write(online_pdf_file.read())
# print(pdf_to_text(pdf_memory_file))


# online pdf to text by requests
response = requests.get('http://www.dabeaz.com/python/UnderstandingGIL.pdf')
pdf_memory_file = io.BytesIO()
pdf_memory_file.write(response.content)
print(pdf_to_text(pdf_memory_file))

# extract metadata
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser
from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument
from pdfminer.pdftypes import resolve1

parser = PDFParser(pdf_memory_file)
doc = PDFDocument(parser)
metadata=doc.info[0]
for k in metadata:
    print(k, resolve1(metadata[k]))
```

Comment: This works perfectly fine for my purpose. However, I had an additional requirement of finding out some metadata from the online pdf- such as Title of the pdf, no of lines, name of the author etc. I have found code for the ones saved in hard drive, but it does not work with the online pdf.  COuld you please help?

Comment: @BitopanGogoi  I have added related code in the edited code, have fun

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use pdftotext library for extracting text.

```
import pdftotext
fh = open(document_name, 'rb')
pdf = pdftotext.PDF(fh)
text = ""
for page in pdf:
    text += page
print(text)
```

Comment: pdftotext is not installing in windows, i have tried it

Comment: Please follow this link it may helpful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52336495/cannot-install-pdftotext-on-windows-because-of-poppler

Comment: path = 'localpath\\pdftotext.exe'
import subprocess
subprocess.call([path])
fh = open("https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/cancer/9/0/9_KJ00003588219/_pdf/-char/en", 'rb')
pdf = subprocess.PDF(fh)
text = ""
for page in pdf:
    text += page
print(text)

Comment: once check the above code it is giving options when execute, can you help me on this

Comment: Hi Sorry for late reply please check once you are getting pdf file in fh variable or not.