# Extract metadata info from online pdf using pdfminer in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, pdfminer, pdf-scraping

I am interested to find out some metadata of an online pdf using pdfminer. I am interested in extracting info such as Title, author, no of lines etc from the pdf

I am trying to use a related solution discussed in-
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60151816/15143974

Which uses the following code-

```
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
import io
import urllib.request
import requests


def pdf_to_text(pdf_file):
    text_memory_file = io.StringIO()

    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, text_memory_file, laparams=LAParams())
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
# get first 3 pages of the pdf file
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(pdf_file, pagenos=(0, 1, 2)):
        interpreter.process_page(page)
    text = text_memory_file.getvalue()
    text_memory_file.close()
    return text

# # online pdf to text by urllib
# online_pdf_file=urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.dabeaz.com/python/UnderstandingGIL.pdf')
# pdf_memory_file=io.BytesIO()
# pdf_memory_file.write(online_pdf_file.read())
# print(pdf_to_text(pdf_memory_file))


# online pdf to text by requests
response = requests.get('http://www.dabeaz.com/python/UnderstandingGIL.pdf')
pdf_memory_file = io.BytesIO()
pdf_memory_file.write(response.content)
print(pdf_to_text(pdf_memory_file))
```

However, I am not able to find where to make the required changes to this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find [pdfplumber](https://github.com/jsvine/pdfplumber) of interest - it's built on top of `pdfminer.six` and simplfies a lot of tasks.

```
import io
import pdfplumber
import requests

url = "http://www.dabeaz.com/python/UnderstandingGIL.pdf"
content = io.BytesIO(requests.get(url).content)

pdf = pdfplumber.open(content)
```

```
>>> pdf.metadata
{'Title': 'UnderstandingGIL',
 'Author': 'David Beazley',
 'Subject': '',
 'Producer': 'Mac OS X 10.6.2 Quartz PDFContext',
 'Creator': 'Keynote',
 'CreationDate': "D:20100220124003Z00'00'",
 'ModDate': "D:20100220124003Z00'00'",
 'Keywords': '',
 'AAPL:Keywords': ['']}
```

Answer (score 2):

As pdfplumber was accepted as an answer, I guess you might also be interested in how to extract metadata using `pypdf` ([docs](https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/metadata.html)):

```py
from pypdf import PdfReader

reader = PdfReader("example.pdf")

meta = reader.metadata

print(len(reader.pages))

# All of the following could be None!
print(meta.title)
print(meta.author)
print(meta.creator)
print(meta.producer)
print(meta.subject)

print(meta.creation_date)     # in contrast to other libraries, pypdf gives you
print(meta.modification_date) # a datetime object for those two
```

PDF can also have another type of metadata:

```py
reader = PdfReader("example.pdf")
xmp_info = reader.xmp_metadata
if xmp_info:
    xmp_info.dc_contributor
    xmp_info.dc_coverage
    xmp_info.dc_creator
    xmp_info.dc_date
    xmp_info.dc_description
    xmp_info.dc_format
    xmp_info.dc_identifier
    xmp_info.dc_language
    xmp_info.dc_publisher
    xmp_info.dc_relation
    xmp_info.dc_rights
    xmp_info.dc_source
    xmp_info.dc_subject
    xmp_info.dc_title
    xmp_info.dc_type
    xmp_info.pdf_keywords
    xmp_info.pdf_pdfversion
    xmp_info.pdf_producer
    xmp_info.xmp_create_date
    xmp_info.xmp_modify_date
    xmp_info.xmp_metadata_date
    xmp_info.xmp_creator_tool
    xmp_info.xmpmm_document_id
    xmp_info.xmpmm_instance_id
    xmp_info.custom_properties
```

You can use the command line tool [`pdfly meta example.pdf`](https://pypi.org/project/pdfly/) to explore PDFs.