# Exception has occurred: ImportError DLL load failed while importing pdftotext: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, django, pdftotext

I am new to Python and currently having trouble when importing some libraries.
I have install pdftotext via `pip install pdftotext` and  `conda install -c conda-forge poppler` after following the instruction from this link [Unable to install pdftotext on Python 3.6, missing poppler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45912641/unable-to-install-pdftotext-on-python-3-6-missing-poppler/58139729#58139729)

Now I get the following error when I try to import pdftotext using visual studio code;

```
Exception has occurred: ImportError
DLL load failed while importing pdftotext: The specified module could not be found.
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post the whole error stack trace?

Comment: I have updated the error `Exception has occurred: ImportError
DLL load failed while importing pdftotext: The specified module could not be found.` I am getting the kindly, check

Comment: is the code running inside a virtual env? can you run `import pdftotext` inside a python shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Trying and researching, I finally got it.

I ran this command on cmd `pip install pdftotext==2.1.4`

Answer (score 0):

Personally I have had the same question. I have solved it by

1. conda update conda .

Then I redo the same procedure as before

2. conda install -c conda-forge poppler
3. pip install pdftotext

After this 3 steps I import successfully pdftotext. I hope it also works for you.

Answer (score -1):

i am having the same issue, the weird thing being that pdftotext used to work just fine on my pc running windows 10, i can't even run `import pdftotext` in the python shell (i get the same error you got), reinstalling anaconda didn't change anything

Comment: Run this `pdftotext==2.1.4`

Comment: what is that supposed to do ? I ran it on cmd and it just outputs "I/O Error: Couldn't open file '==2.1.4': No error."

Comment: run like this `pip install pdftotext==2.1.4`

Comment: My pdftotext was already on version 2.1.4, anyway i uninstalled it and reinstalled it with ==2.1.4 but the error is still there, too bad, maybe we have different issues