How to extract data from pdfs which are not in tables or containers into a column based table format in python?
I am trying to convert my pdf data into structured table format data. I have tried bunch of options but none of them have been able to separate fields into columns of table format. I am able to do that using AI models like LlamaParse where fields get separated by | but unfortunately I cant use Llama for now because of this issue
Some other options that I have tried below:

pdfplumber:
import pandas as pd
import pdfplumber

path = r"my_pdf_file.pdf"

data = []

with pdfplumber.open(path) as pdf:
    pages = pdf.pages
    for p in pages:
            data.append(p.extract_tables())

print(data)

with pdfplumber.open(path) as pdf:
    first_page = pdf.pages[0]

first_page.to_image()


By below code I am able to extract only the top section of personal info but not the required test results which are separated by a lot of spaces.
data[0][0][0][0].splitlines()

['Patient Name : Mr.VINEET',
 'Age/Sex : 39 YRS/M Lab Id. : 012408030006',
 'Refered By : Self Sample Collection On : 03/Aug/2024 08:30AM',
 'Collected By : HARPREET Sample Lab Rec.On : 03/Aug/2024 11:50 AM',
 'Collection Mode : HOME COLLECTION Reporting On : 03/Aug/2024 03:24 PM',
 'BarCode : 10593974']

so basically what this is able to give me is only the above containerized section of PDF and not the below required data which are separated by large number of white spaces:
pages.to_image().debug_tablefinder()



PdfReader:
this also gives only text format and nothing structured
from pypdf import PdfReader
reader = PdfReader(path)
reader.pages[0].extract_text().splitlines()

output:
['NEW AAROGYA EXECUTIVE PACKAGE 108 TEST',
 'Kidney Function Test (KFT),Serum',
 'BLOOD UREA',
 '(Method : Urease-GLDH)31.80 12-43 mg/dL',
 'BLOOD UREA NITROGEN (BUN)',
 '(Method : Calculated)15 6 - 21 mg/dl',
 'SERUM CREATININE',
 '(Method : Modified Jaffe,s)1.10 0.9 - 1.3 mg/dL',
 ' ',
 'Creatinine is a by product of muscle catabolism. It is filtered by kidney and excreted in the urine. if the filtering of the kidney is deficient, creatinine levels in blood are',
 'increased.',
 ' ',
 'Creatine level is used for the assessment of kidney function and to diagnose renal dysfunction. However, more important than absolute creatinine level is the trend of',
 'serum creatinine levels over time. Serum creatine is especially useful in evaluation of glomerular function. BUN (Blood Urea Nitrogen) & Creatine are frequently',
 'compared. If BUN increased and creatinine is normal, dehydration is present; and if both increased, then renal disorder is present.',
 ' ',
 'Conditions associated with increased creatine level   : Acute and chronic renal failure, shock (prolonged), systemic lupus erythematosis, cancer, leukemia ,',
 'hypertension, acute myocardial infaction, diabetic nephropathy , diet rich in creatinine (e.g. beef), congenital renal disease etc.  ',
 'Condition associated with decreased creatine level : Pregnancy, Eclampsia etc.',
 ' ',
 'Opinion & Advice:',
 'People with increased creatine levels are advised to undergo : Kidney Function Test, Urine Examination & USG (Whole abdomen) at regular intervals.',
 'Decreased creatine levels are usually insignificant.',
 'SERUM URIC ACID',
 '(Method : Uricase-POD)5.8 3.5-7.2 mg/dL',
 'UREA / CREATININE RATIO',
 '(Method : Calculated)28.91 23 - 33 Ratio',
 'BUN / CREATININE RATIO',
 '(Method : Calculated)13.51 5.5 - 19.2 Ratio',
 'INORGANIC PHOSPHORUS',
 '(Method : UV Molybdate)3.63 2.5-4.5 mg/dL',

Even this doesn't give any tabular data.

pytesseract:
import os
from PIL import Image
import pdf2image
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
import pytesseract

img = Image.open(r"saved_image.png")

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
text

output:
'OF tata\n\nOe\n\nLABORATORY TEST REPORT\n\nPatient Name >Mr.VINEET\n\nAge/Sex :39 YRS/M Lab Id. : 012408030006\nRefered By : Self Sample Collection On : 03/Aug/2024 08:30AM\n\nCollected By > HARPREET Sample Lab Rec.On : 03/Aug/2024 11:50 AM\nCollection Mode :HOME COLLECTION Reporting On : 03/Aug/2024 03:24 PM\nBarCode : 10593974\n\nTest Name Result Biological Ref. Int. Unit\n\nNEW AAROGYA EXECUTIVE PACKAGE 108 TEST\nKidney Function Test (KFT),Serum\n\nBLOOD UREA 31.80 12-43 mg/dL\n(Method ; Urease-GLDH)\n\nBLOOD UREA NITROGEN (BUN) 15 6-21 mg/dl\n(Method : Calculated)\n\nSERUM CREATININE 1.10 0.9-1.3 mg/dL\n\n(Method : Modified Jaffe,s)\n\nCreatinine is a by product of muscle catabolism. It is filtered by kidney and excreted in the urine. if the filtering of the kidney is deficient, creatinine levels in blood are\nincreased.\n\nCreatine level is used for the assessment of kidney function and to diagnose renal dysfunction. However, more important than absolute creatinine level is the trend of\nserum creatinine levels over time. Serum creatine is especially useful in evaluation of glomerular function. BUN (Blood Urea Nitrogen) & Creatine are frequently\ncompared. If BUN increased and creatinine is normal, dehydration Is present; and if both increased, then renal disorder is present.\n\nConditions associated with increased creatine level : Acute and chronic renal failure, shock (prolonged), systemic lupus erythematosis, cancer, leukemia ,\nhypertension, acute myocardial infaction, diabetic nephropathy , diet rich in creatinine (e.g. beef), congenital renal disease etc.\nCondition associated with decreased creatine level : Pregnancy, Eclampsia etc.\n\nOpinion & Advice:\nPeople with increased creatine levels are advised to undergo : Kidney Function Test, Urine Examination & USG (Whole abdomen) at regular intervals.\nDecreased creatine levels are usually insignificant.\n\nSERUM URIC ACID 5.8 3.5-7.2 mg/dL\n(Method : Uricase-POD)\n\nUREA / CREATININE RATIO 28.91 23-33 Ratio\n(Method : Calculated)\n\nBUN / CREATININE RATIO 13.51 5.5- 19.2 Ratio\n(Method : Calculated)\n\nINORGANIC PHOSPHORUS 3.63 2.5-4.5 mg/dL\n\n(Method : UV Molybdate)\n\na\n\n5 SS\n.—— =\n\nDR. ASHOK MALHOTRA DR. SANJEEV R. SAIGAL DR. B. JUNEJA |\nMBBS, MD (BIOCHEMISTRY) PHD (MEDICAL MICROBIOLOGY) MBBS, MD (PATHOLOGY)\n\nCONDITIONS OF REPORTING\n\ni) «) @) @)\n\nThe reported results are for information and for interpretation of the referring doctor only. 3 It is presumed that the tests performed on the specimen belong to the patient named or identified.\nResults of the tests may vary from laboratory to laboratory and also in some parameters from time to time forthe same patient 2 Should the results indicate an unexpected abnormally, the same should be reconfirmed.\nOnly such medical professionals who understand reporting units, reference ranges and limitations of technologies should interpret results. =< This report is not valid for medicotegal purposes.\n\nPage 1 of 20\n\nNeither Aarogya Pathcare, nor its employees / representatives assume any liability, responsibility for any loss or damages that may be incurred by any person as a result of persuming the meaning or contents of the r\n\nSUGGESTIONS\nValues out of reference range requires reconfirmation before starting any medical treatments. 3 Retesting is needed if you suspect any quality shotcomings. = Testing or retesting should be done iin accredited laboratories. 2 ff any complaint / Suggestion call : 7627957531, 7011346653\n\n7\nol\n\n'

sample output from above string:
n\nBLOOD UREA NITROGEN (BUN) 15 6-21 mg/dl\n(Method : Calculated)\n\nSERUM CREATININE 1.10 0.9-1.3 mg/dL\n\n



Desired output:
BLOOD UREA NITROGEN (BUN)|15|6-21|mg/dl
(Method : Calculated)
SERUM CREATININE|1.10|0.9-1.3|mg/dL

I was able to do this in R as it was able to capture large white spaces and then I replaced them with delimiter like | to maintain separation
Same thing I was able to do using Llama_Parse but I am not able to use this in Streamlit so looking for alternatives. So I Need a solution in Python without AI models like Llama_parse.

Thanks alot @KJ. pdftotext with layout seems like a perfect option in my case but installing this package is another challenge in windows. So far I have not been able to install it. Is there any alternative to this package that provide similar layout option or functionality that you are aware of ?

ooh ok .. I was installing these from conda & pip and was constantly getting error. Let me try the way as you have suggested. Thanks again !!!

@KJ where should I keep this unpacked files folder ? I tried to follow the steps of placing files through this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45912641/unable-to-install-pdftotext-on-python-3-6-missing-poppler and https://coder.haus/2019/09/27/installing-pdftotext-through-pip-on-windows-10/ but I am still stuck with errors.

@KJ thank you so much for guiding me through all these steps and explaining them.  Really Appreciate it. Will try using it without python. Thanks alot again :) . This was a big help !!!

Sure it puts everything in place in that case. Thanks alot @KJ . Appreciate your help :)

@KJ for now I have used AI to parse the documents as I was able to integrate streamlit with AI and have not worked on pdftotext in python. But I will do that as a non AI solution. Will update the solution once I work on it.
